# Fibonacci + Fizz Buzz = Fibo Nacci!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, sequence, fibonacci

Fibonacci + FizzBuzz = Fibo Nacci!

---

## Your challenge is to create a Fibo Nacci program!

- A Fibo Nacci program outputs the first **100** Fibonacci numbers (starting from 1).
- If the Fibonacci number is divisible by both 2 **and** 3 (i.e. it is divisible by 6), then output FiboNacci instead of the number.
- Otherwise, if the Fibonacci number is divisible by 2, then output Fibo instead of the number.
- Otherwise, if the Fibonacci number is divisible by 3, then output Nacci instead of the number.

## Rules

- The program should take no input.
- The program should output a new line (`\n`) after every entry.
- The program should **not** print anything to STDERR.
- The program **must** output the first **100** Fibo Nacci entries (starting from 1).
- Standard loopholes are not allowed (by default).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins!

Here is the expected output:

```
1
1
Fibo
Nacci
5
Fibo
13
Nacci
Fibo
55
89
FiboNacci
233
377
Fibo
Nacci
1597
Fibo
4181
Nacci
Fibo
17711
28657
FiboNacci
75025
121393
Fibo
Nacci
514229
Fibo
1346269
Nacci
Fibo
5702887
9227465
FiboNacci
24157817
39088169
Fibo
Nacci
165580141
Fibo
433494437
Nacci
Fibo
1836311903
2971215073
FiboNacci
7778742049
12586269025
Fibo
Nacci
53316291173
Fibo
139583862445
Nacci
Fibo
591286729879
956722026041
FiboNacci
2504730781961
4052739537881
Fibo
Nacci
17167680177565
Fibo
44945570212853
Nacci
Fibo
190392490709135
308061521170129
FiboNacci
806515533049393
1304969544928657
Fibo
Nacci
5527939700884757
Fibo
14472334024676221
Nacci
Fibo
61305790721611591
99194853094755497
FiboNacci
259695496911122585
420196140727489673
Fibo
Nacci
1779979416004714189
Fibo
4660046610375530309
Nacci
Fibo
19740274219868223167
31940434634990099905
FiboNacci
83621143489848422977
135301852344706746049
Fibo
Nacci
```

### The Catalogue

The <s>Snack</s> Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalogue from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

If there you want to include multiple numbers in your header (e.g. because your score is the sum of two files or you want to list interpreter flag penalties separately), make sure that the actual score is the *last* number in the header:

```
## Perl, 43 + 2 (-p flag) = 45 bytes
```

You can also make the language name a link which will then show up in the snippet:

```
## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 121 bytes
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 63442; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 41805; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,<]*(?:<(?:[^\n>]*>[^\n<]*<\/[^\n>]*>)[^\n,<]*)*),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    else console.log(body);
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    lang = jQuery('<a>'+lang+'</a>').text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, lang_raw: lang, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() > b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    if (a.lang_raw.toLowerCase() < b.lang_raw.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Shortest Solution by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What about languages with highest integer type of only 64 bits? :( Isn't 90 fib. numbers enough?

Comment: @Zereges In that matter, I am sorry. :(

Comment: Do you mean "at least 100"? Or is printing more than 100 not allowed?

Comment: Maybe it should be called "Fizzo Nacci"

Comment: @mbomb007 Where is the "at least"?

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος It never says "at least". I think the point of the question is if it would be allowed to print more than 100 Fibo Nacci numbers.

Comment: @DanTheMan The program should only output the first 100 Fibo Nacci numbers, no more, no less.

Comment: Would be a much better question if it only required native int support :(

Comment: @SztupY If I were to make a change now, everyone else's answers would have to change to just the first 80 or 90 numbers.

Comment: @SztupY Because the output in this question is completely invariant, you don't even need integers at all. Just treat this question as a [tag:kolmogorov-complexity] question (I even added the tag) and go from there.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it's still an unnecessarry limitation, that might make creative implementators steer clear of this task. And most of the solutions (including the 2nd most upvoted one) are breaking already

Comment: :( @ approx-66-bit int requirement

Comment: Fibo Nazi (lol)

Comment: Math comment: every third Fibonacci number is even, and every fourth Fibonacci number is a multiple of 3. This might lead to alternate coding strategies, which don't require testing divisibility.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58615/41024)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Pyth, 37 bytes

I loop through the Fibonacci numbers instead of generating them beforehand, since it's really short to do.

```
K1V100|+*"Fibo"!%=+Z~KZ2*"Nacci"!%Z3Z
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K1V100%7C%2B%2a%22Fibo%22%21%25%3D%2BZ%7EKZ2%2a%22Nacci%22%21%25Z3Z&debug=0)

Comment: Congratulations for winning this challenge! I liked that this solution was fast.

Answer (score 50):

### Python 2, 62 bytes

```py
a=b=1;exec"print~a%2*'Fibo'+~a%3/2*'Nacci'or a;a,b=b,a+b;"*100
```

Not much different from the standard FizzBuzz, really.

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: I need to remember this looping construct for my next Ruby golf. This is amazing.

Answer (score 22):

## C++11 metaprogramming, 348 bytes

```
#include<iostream>
#define D static const unsigned long long v=
template<int L>struct F{D F<L-1>::v+F<L-2>::v;};template<>struct F<2>{D 1;};template<>struct F<1>{D 1;};template<int Z>struct S:S<Z-1>{S(){auto&s=std::cout;auto l=F<Z>::v;s<<(l%2?"":"Fibo")<<(l%3?"":"Nacci");(l%2&&l%3?s<<l:s)<<"\n";}};template<>struct S<0>{S(){}};int main(){S<100>s;}
```

Because, why not. It compiles with `warning C4307: '+': integral constant overflow`, runs fine, but 93+ th Fibonacci numbers are not shown correctly (due to overflow), so this is invalid entry (but I could not win it with that much of bytes though)

Ungolfed

```
#include <iostream>
#define D static const unsigned long long v = 
template<int L>struct F { D F<L - 1>::v + F<L - 2>::v; };
template<>struct F<2> { D 1; };
template<>struct F<1> { D 1; };

template<int Z>struct S : S<Z - 1>
{
    S()
    {
        auto&s = std::cout;
        auto l = F<Z>::v;
        s << (l % 2 ? "" : "Fibo")
          << (l % 3 ? "" : "Nacci");
        (l % 2 && l % 3 ? s << l : s) << "\n";
    }
};

template<>struct S<0>
{
    S() { }
};

int main()
{
    S<100>s;
}
```

Comment: You could use exploded strings (`template <char H, char ...T>`) in your templates to (theoretically) handle arbitrary-length values. Then it would just be a matter of examining the last 2 characters in each string to determine divisibility by 2 and/or 3.

Comment: @Mego I do not understand you. How it would help me to handle values, which do not fit into 64 bits. Also, You need all digits to find out if the number is divisible by 3.

Comment: Strings can be arbitrarily long (until you run out of memory). And you're right, I messed up my comment. Still, you could compute the digital sum to determine divisibility by 3.

Comment: @Mego Implementing addition of those strings would require much more effort.

Comment: Perhaps, but at least it would be a valid entry.

Comment: You could use the gnu dialect and use `__uint128_t`, maybe.

Answer (score 14):

### C#, <s>175 171 152</s> 145 bytes

```
class c{static void Main(){for(dynamic a=1m,b=a,c=0;c++<100;b=a+(a=b))System.Console.WriteLine(a%6>0?a%2>0?a%3>0?a:"Nacci":"Fibo":"FiboNacci");}}
```

Uncompressed:

```
class c {
    static void Main()
    {
        for (dynamic a = 1m, b = a, c = 0; c++ < 100; b = a + (a = b))
            System.Console.WriteLine(a%6>0?a%2>0?a%3>0?a:"Nacci":"Fibo":"FiboNacci");
    }
}
```

Comment: Even compressing the output with a DeflateStream the lowest I could get was 191 chars so this is likely very close to the best possible c# answer. A shame BigInteger is required.

Comment: "using System;" will give another -1 in size.

Comment: I still had to prefix System.Numerics with System despite the using :-S, so I'm not sure the using will work.

Comment: Yes, the same here (under Mono) :(

Comment: Another trick to make it 3 bytes shorter

Comment: You can save 3 characters by replacing the `==0`s with `>0` and inverting the ternaries: `class c{static void Main(){for(System.Numerics.BigInteger a=1,b=1,c=0;c++<100;b=a+(a=b))System.Console.WriteLine(a%6>0?a%2>0?a%3>0?a:(object)"Nacci":"Fibo":"FiboNacci");}}`

Comment: That's a great idea! Let me check

Comment: You can save another 7 characters by changing `decimal a=1,b=1` to `dynamic a=1m,b=a` and then you can lose the `(object)` :)

Comment: Great, @Timwi! That gonna be final word.

Comment: Using `dynamic` is pretty clever

Answer (score 14):

### Oracle SQL, 212 bytes

Not a golfing language but I had to try...

Concatenating all the rows with `\n`:

```
WITH F(R,P,C)AS(SELECT 1,0,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT R+1,C,P+C FROM F WHERE R<100)SELECT LISTAGG(NVL(DECODE(MOD(C,2),0,'Fibo')||DECODE(MOD(C,3),0,'Nacci'),''||C),CHR(13))WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY R)||CHR(13)FROM F
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/10484)

Or with one entry from the sequence per row (162 bytes):

```
WITH F(R,P,C)AS(SELECT 1,0,1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT R+1,C,P+C FROM F WHERE R<100)SELECT NVL(DECODE(MOD(C,2),0,'Fibo')||DECODE(MOD(C,3),0,'Nacci'),''||C)FROM F
```

Comment: Awesome, just for using SQL

Comment: Just use the last one, since it is the "equivalent" to outputting "per line". And it really is a fine piece of code. Well done!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel If it's run in SQL*Plus (or another command line interface) then there will be a newline output after each row (as part of how it reports the query output). However, that is a function of the CLI and not the SQL language - to be compliant with the rule `The program should output a new line (\n) after every entry` I'll leave it as the longer code but the shorter one could be made compliant (without relying on a CLI) by adding `||CHR(13)` before the final `FROM` for 171 chracters.

Comment: Couldn't you use `"\n"`? Seems to work on MySQL. (Running `select length("\n")` returns 1, and running `select "\n"` doesn't return `n`, as with `select "\p"` returns `p` due to being an invalid escape)

Comment: `SELECT LENGTH('\n') FROM DUAL` outputs `2` in Oracle as `'\n'` does not get converted to `CHR(13)`.

Answer (score 11):

## [ShapeScript](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/ShapeScript), 83 bytes

```
11'1?1?+'77*2**!""'"%r
"@+@0?2%1<"Fibo"*1?3%1<"Nacci"*+0?_0>"@"*!#%'52*0?**!"'"$""~
```

[Try it online!](http://shapescript.tryitonline.net/#code=MTEnMT8xPysnNzcqMioqISIiJyIlcgoiQCtAMD8yJTE8IkZpYm8iKjE_MyUxPCJOYWNjaSIqKzA_XzA-IkAiKiEjJSc1MiowPyoqISInIiQiIn4=&input=)

Comment: Literally looks like my cat jumped on top of my keyboard while I tried to turn on sticky keys. Nice job.

Comment: @phase figuratively. Either that or you're not looking too closely. Or you have a tiny cat or a giant keyboard. Because this cat managed to type Fibo and Nacci but otherwise avoid all letter keys save for one r.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think phase has macros setup for that ;)

Comment: @phase 1. Why is your cat in your room?; 2. why would you want to turn on sticky keys? 3? Why do you not have a cat trap box on your desk to avoid your cat jumping on your keyboard?

Answer (score 8):

### Mathematica, 80 bytes

```
a=b_/;#∣b&;Print/@(Fibonacci@Range@100/.{a@6->FiboNacci,a@2->Fibo,a@3->Nacci})
```

Adaptation of my older FizzBuzz solution.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sorry, fixed. Also, for versions less than 10.3, replace `Echo` with `Print`.

Answer (score 8):

## Java, <s>407</s> <s>398</s> <s>351</s> 308 bytes

Golfed it with help from @Geobits and @SamYonnou

Spread the word: `Verbose == Java`

```
import java.math.*;class A{public static void main(String[]w){BigInteger a=BigInteger.ZERO,b=a.flipBit(0),c,z=a,t=a.flipBit(1),h=t.flipBit(0),s=t.flipBit(2);for(int i=0;i<100;i++){System.out.println(b.mod(s).equals(z)?"FiboNacci":b.mod(t).equals(z)?"Fibo":b.mod(h).equals(z)?"Nacci":b);c=a;a=b;b=c.add(b);}}}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
import java.math.*;

class A
{
  public static void main(String[]w)
  {
    BigInteger a=BigInteger.ZERO,b=a.flipBit(0),c,z=a,t=a.flipBit(1),h=t.flipBit(0),s=t.flipBit‌​(2);
    for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
      System.out.println(b.mod(s).equals(z)?"FiboNacci":b.mod(t).equals‌​(z)?"Fibo":b.mod(h).equals(z)?"Nacci":b);                
      c=a;a=b;b=c.add(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be golfed more. Import `java.math.*` instead of the whole thing. Use the constants for `ONE` and `ZERO` instead of `new` BigIntegers. Remove the `public` from the class. Pack everything except the `println` statement in the `for` body inside the loop declaration, etc. I recommend looking over the [Java golfing tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/6671/14215) in general.

Comment: @Geobits Done! 'Twas a pity that I was unfamiliar with `BigInteger` and its various golfing techniques.

Comment: Storing BigInteger.ZERO, using flipBit(...) as an alternative to new BigInteger(...), and some other minor things you can get it down to 308: `import java.math.*;class A{public static void main(String[]w){BigInteger a=BigInteger.ZERO,b=a.flipBit(0),c,z=a,t=a.flipBit(1),h=t.flipBit(0),s=t.flipBit(2);for(int i=0;i<100;i++){System.out.println(b.mod(s).equals(z)?"FiboNacci":b.mod(t).equals(z)?"Fibo":b.mod(h).equals(z)?"Nacci":b);c=a;a=b;b=c.add(b);}}}`

Comment: Looks like `BigInteger` always returns `BigInteger.ZERO` when some operation like `add(...)` evaluates to zero so you can use `==` instead of `.equals(z)`, also you can do away with storing `s=t.flipBit‌​(2)` (6) and instead do some clever inner assignment like so: `import java.math.*;class A{public static void main(String[]w){BigInteger a=BigInteger.ZERO,b=a.flipBit(0),c,d,z=a,t=a.flipBit(1),h=t.flipBit(0);for(int i=0;i<100;i++){System.out.println((c=b.mod(t)).add(d=b.mod(h))==z?"FiboNacci":c==z?"Fibo":d==z?"Nacci":b);c=a;a=b;b=c.add(b);}}}` these changes get it down to 280

Comment: Oh and for the same reason you can use `==` for comparing to zero you can use it for the inner assignment bit and replace `(c=b.mod(t)).add(d=b.mod(h))==z` with `(c=b.mod(t))==(d=b.mod(h))` bringing the total length to 275

Comment: Take advantage of the Properties of the Fibonacci numbers and you can do it with 42 chars less:
Remove the variable z and change the println to
System.out.println(i%12==0?"FiboNacci":i%3==0?"Fibo":i%4==0?"Nacci":b);
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Primes_and_divisibility

Comment: @FabianTschachtli The `%` cannot be used on a `BigInteger`. That is why I use the `.mod()` function.

Comment: @Sock Notice that he is using `%` on `i`, not the BigInteger. For Fibonacci numbers the divisibility of the number is related to divisibility of the index in the sequence, see the WP link.

Comment: interface a{static void ....

Comment: I think you mean `Verbose.isEqualTo(Java)`

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>71</s> 66 bytes

```
a=b=1;100.times{puts [b,f='Fibo',n='Nacci',f,b,f+n][~b%6];a=b+b=a}
```

#### ungolfed:

```
a = b = 1 #starting values
100.times{
  # create an array, and selects a value depending on the current number
  puts([b, 'Fibo', 'Nacci', 'Fibo', b, 'FiboNacci'][~b%6])
  a=b+b=a # magic
}
```

Comment: I've worked on this for longer than I'd like to admin and can't find any way to improve it. `f,n=%w[Fibo Nacci]`,`f,n='Fibbo','Nacci'` and `f='Fibbo';n='Nacci'` all have the same character count. +1

Comment: You can save three bytes by using `[b,f='Fibo',n='Nacci',f,b,f+n][~b%6]`, and two more by removing the parentheses in `a=b+b=a`.

Comment: Thank you @primo. That is a neat trick with the `~` operator. Never seen it before. And now I know why negative indexes are part of ruby:)

Comment: Really need `puts [` instead of `puts[`?

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ yes. `puts[...][...]` groups as `(puts[...])[...]` rater than `puts([...][...])`

Comment: Roses are red, Violets are blue, for Haskell and Ruby, I have no clue.

Comment: I love the symmetry in `a=b+b=a`

Answer (score 7):

## [><>](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 116 bytes

```
01:n1&61>.
ao:@+:v
vv?%2:<
">:3%?vv^16<
o>:3%?!v~v<&
bov"ci"< 6 ;
io"   n  6~?
Focv1&<   o=
"o">+:aa*!o^
>^>"aN"ooo^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HccxCgIxEAXQfk4xO7ApXBBHIcUYEytLjxCIC2Ka/YUw5V49gq977/79jHFS2zREzUdqsPtiTu5lPlsiyXaZi3vVmAj/TL57CvSCy9olceQrdQgzb8xxL/TA6hpSVMaNBJIXa@0woVKuWdpTANQxfg)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Comment: You could probably combine both the `3%` sections

Comment: @JoKing You'd think so, but they actually lead to different outcomes if n%3!=0. I'm sure there **is** a way to combine them, but it would mean restructuring the entire program, and I imagine it would actually be longer.

Answer (score 6):

### C#, <s>498</s> <s>392</s> 320 bytes

I just really wanted to do this with linq, too bad I had to write my own sum function for BigInteger that really killed it :-(

```
using System.Linq;using System.Numerics;using System.Collections.Generic;static class a{static void Main(){var f=new List<BigInteger>(){1,1};while(f.Count<100)f.Add(f.Skip(f.Count-2).Take(2).Aggregate((a,b)=>b+a));f.ForEach(x=>{System.Console.WriteLine(x%6==0?"FiboNacci":x%2==0?"Fibo":x%3==0?"Nacci":x.ToString());});}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class a
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var f=new List<BigInteger>(){1,1};
        while(f.Count<100)
            f.Add(f.Skip(f.Count-2).Take(2).Aggregate((a,b)=>b+a));
        f.ForEach(x=>
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(x%6==0?"FiboNacci":x%2==0?"Fibo":x%3==0?"Nacci":x.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

Edit: Down to 320 bytes thanks to LegionMammal978 for the aggregate suggestion and thanks to olegz's C# answer for the x%6 shorthand for X%2 && x%3 as well as the use of ternary operators in a single WriteLine statement.

Comment: Have you heard of the `Aggregate` LINQ function?

Comment: Replace "sum" with "t" to shave 6 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 39

```
Vtu+Gs>2G99U2|+*!%N2"Fibo"*!%N3"Nacci"N
```

Very similar to the standard fizzbuzz solution, just with a generator for the Fibonacci numbers.

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Vtu%2BGs%3E2G99U2%7C%2B%2A%21%25N2%22Fibo%22%2A%21%25N3%22Nacci%22N&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <strike>171</strike> 121 bytes

"Brute force approach."

```
a=[1,1]
print 1
for _ in"q"*99:print[a[1],"Fibo","Nacci","FiboNacci"][a.append(a.pop(0)+a[0])or(1-a[0]%2)+(a[0]%3<1)*2]
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 100 bytes

```
x=[1,1]
exec"x+=[x[-1]+x[-2]];"*98
print"\n".join(["Fibo"*(i%2==0)+"Nacci"*(i%3==0)or`i`for i in x])
```

For the large numbers, adds a `L` to the end showing it's a long number.

If that's a problem, here is a 104 byte solution

```
x=[1,1]
exec"x+=[x[-1]+x[-2]];"*98
print"\n".join(["Fibo"*(i%2==0)+"Nacci"*(i%3==0)or str(i)for i in x])
```

Comment: You can shorten the `for` loop using this tip: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5047/42736. In particular the `exec` tip looks good.

Comment: +1 for the `exec <program_string>*n` trick. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

### Javascript, <s>93 90 86</s> 84 Bytes

```
for(a=0,b=1,i=100;i--;a=[b,b+=a][0])console.log((b%2?'':'Fibo')+(b%3?'':'Nacci')||b)
```

Comment: You could save four bytes by changing `a=[b,b=a+b][0]` to `b=a+b,a=b-a`. Also, in a completely unrelated note, I like the way you answer like really fast in Stack Overflow hehe Have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript(ES6), <s>137</s> 134 bytes

```
g=x=>(a=[1,1],f=(x)=>(a[x]=y=a[x-1]+a[x-2],(y%2&&y%3?y:(!(y%2)?'Fibo':'')+(!(y%3)?'Nacci':''))+'\n'+((++x<99)?f(x):'')),'1\n1\n'+f(2))
```

Recursive function that calculates fibonnacci, put it in an array then output Fibo,Nacci or the number and call itself to calculate next until 100.

It breaks at 73 because of javascript Number precision. Only way to get around that would be to add my own bit calculation.

Comment: This doesn't work, it goes wrong after `5527939700884757 + 8944394323791464 = 14472334024676220` when it should be `14472334024676221` because JavaScript uses 16 bit precision floats and that requires 17 bits of precision. You should also print `1` twice.

Comment: Added the print 1 twice. For the precision, I need to change everythin on the code to make it work (not using Number but Uint32Array and doing computation bits by bits)

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, <s>128</s> 119 bytes

```
111&v       >:3%0=?v>  v
?;ao>:2%0=?v :3%0=?v :n>:}+&:1+&aa*=
            ^oooo < ^ooooo <
           >"obiF"^>"iccaN"^
```

I <s>shamelessly stole</s> borrowed an existing program FizzBuzz program and modified it to work for the Fibo Nacci sequence. <s>It outputs numbers forever.</s> Now it is fixed, i.e. it only outputs 100 numbers. Try it [here](http://www.fishlanguage.com/playground/BdK2LsY2pw6aHM2GP).

Comment: You must only output the first 100 Fibo Nacci numbers, no more, no less.

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος I finally got around to making it only output 100 numbers.

Comment: This outputs 101 numbers on TIO but doesn't work at the linked site

Answer (score 2):

### dc, <s>100</s> <s>89</s> 79 bytes

```
[sG[]]sx[dn]s01df[sbdlb+lbrdd2%d[Fibo]r0!=xnr3%d[Nacci]r0!=xn*0!=0APzZ3>o]dsox
```

Inspired by http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DeeCee

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf!

Answer (score 2):

### Wolfram Language, 84 bytes

Kind of cheating of course, because of the built in `Fibonacci`.

```
t=Fibonacci@Range@100;g=(t[[#;;;;#]]=#2)&;g[3,Fibo]g[4,Nacci]g[12,FiboNacci]Print/@t
```

Example command to run the script

```
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel -script ~/Desktop/fibo.wl
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 74 bytes

```perl
map{print+(Fibo)[$_%2].(Nacci)[$_%3]||$_ for$a+=$b||1,$b+=$a}1..50
```

Requires the following command line option: `-lMbigint`, counted as 8.

---

**Sample Usage**

```perl
$ perl -lMbigint fibo-nacci.pl
```

---

**Perl, 79 bytes**

```perl
use bigint;map{print+(Fibo)[$_%2].(Nacci)[$_%3]||$_,$/for$a+=$b||1,$b+=$a}1..50
```

Same as above, without requiring any command line options.

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, 47 bytes

```
100,{1.@{.@+}*;..2%!'Fibo'*\3%!'Nacci'*+\or}%n*
```

---

**Explanation**

```
100,            # push 0..99
{               # map
  1.@           # push 1 twice, rotate counting var to the top
  {             # apply that many times
    .@+         # copy the top, rotate and add
                # if the stack is [a b], this produces: [a b b] -> [b b a] -> [b b+a]
  }*
  ;..           # discard the top, duplicate twice
  2%!'Fibo'*\   # divisible by 2 ? 'Fibo' : ''
  3%!'Nacci'*   # divisible by 3 ? 'Nacci' : ''
  +\or          # concatenate, if empty use the numeric value instead
}%
n*              # join all with a newline
```

Answer (score 2):

## PARI/GP, <s>76</s> 73 bytes

*Saved three bytes courtesy of [Mitch Schwartz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63442/63859?noredirect=1#comment154061_63859).*

```
for(n=b=!a=1,99,b=a+a=b;print(if(b%2,"",Fibo)if(b%3,if(b%2,b,""),Nacci)))
```

---

**Sample Usage**

```
$ gp -qf < fibo-nacci.gp
```

Comment: It's shorter not to use built-in; I got 73 with `for(i=b=!a=1,99,b=a+a=b; ...`

Comment: @MitchSchwartz it used to be called `fibo` ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
тENÅfDÑ23SÃvá.•iÑ+FÌ;•™#yèJ},
```

Inspired by [*@Grimmy*'s bottom answer of the *1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/186380/52210) (doesn't work in the legacy version with `S` removed, because there is a bug in the compressed string `.•iÑ+FÌ;•`; the compiler probably thinks there is an open if/loop block due to the `i`/`F`..).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpOr3@HWNJfDE42Mgw83lx1eqPeoYVHm4Ynabod7rIHMRy2LlCsPr/Cq1fn/HwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
тE                # Loop `N` in the range [1,100]:
  NÅf             #  Get the N'th Fibonacci number
     D            #  Duplicate it
      Ñ           #  Pop this copy, and push a list of its divisors
       23SÃ       #  Only keep the divisors [2,3]
 v                #  Inner loop over those remaining divisors (or not if none are left):
  á               #   Only leave the letters of the current top of the stack
                  #   (to get rid of the Fibonacci number that was still on the stack)
   .•iÑ+FÌ;•      #   Push compressed string "fibo nacci"
            ™     #   Titlecase each: "Fibo Nacci"
             #    #   Split it on spaces: ["Fibo","Nacci"]
              yè  #   Index the current divisor `y` into it (0-based and with wraparound,
                  #   so 2 will index into "Fibo" and 3 into "Nacci")
                J #   Join everything on the stack together
 },               #  After the inner loop: pop and print the top with trailing newline
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `.•iÑ+FÌ;•` is `"fibo nacci"`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `j`, 21 bytes

```
ÞF₁Ẏƛ₍₂₃«-∇j€₌p«⌈ǐ*∑∴
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJqIiwiIiwiw55G4oKB4bqOxpvigo3igoLigoPCqy3iiIdq4oKs4oKMcMKr4oyIx5Aq4oiR4oi0IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Basically the same as the standard 11 byte FizzBuzz with a few changes

### Explained

```
ÞF₁Ẏƛ₍₂₃«-∇j€₌p«⌈ǐ*∑∴
ÞF₁Ẏ                  # The first 100 fibonacci numbers
    ƛ                 # to each item n:
     ₍₂₃              #   push a list [n % 2 == 0, n % 3 == 0]
        «-∇j€₌p«      #   push the string "fibo nacci"
                ⌈ǐ    #   split on spaces and titlecase each
                  *∑  #   vectorised string multiply and sum - this is like writing way of writing ("Fibo" * (n % 2 == 0) + "Naci" * (n % 3 == 0))
                    ∴ #   choose the greatest of n and that string. A number will always be greater than an empty string, and a non-empty string will always be greater than a number
                      # Just like the standard fizzbuzz, the `j` flag joins on newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 51 bytes

```
V.Wn100lHaZ+@Z_1@Z_2[1 1)|+*"Fibo"}2JPN*"Nacci"}3JN
```

Generates the Fibonacci sequence then decides what to print.

```
                    [1 1)                           - H = [1,1]
  Wn100lH                                           - While len(H)!=100 
         aZ+@Z_1@Z_2                                - H.append(H[-1]+H[-2])
V.                                                  - For N in H:
                                    JPN             - Set J to the prime factorization of H
                           *"Fibo"}2J               - If there is a 2 in the factorization, add "Fibo" to a string
                                       *"Nacci"}3J  - If there is a 3 in the factorization, add "Nacci" to a string
                          +                         - Join them together
                         |                        N - If the string isn't empty (If it isn't divisible by 2 or 3), print N
                                                    - Else print the string
```

To test, try this (only does the first 20 numbers)

```
V.Wn20lHaZ+@Z_1@Z_2[1 1)|+*"Fibo"}2JPN*"Nacci"}3JN
```

Comment: How long does it take to run the actual program?

Comment: I have no idea, it didn't in the 30 seconds  it took to work out that working out such large prime factorizations would probably slow it down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### QBasic, <strike>144</strike> 141 bytes

Not particularly small, but it beats C++ and C#

```
r=1:FOR i=1 TO 046:a$="":q=p+r
IF q MOD 2=0 THEN a$="Fibo"
IF q MOD 3=0 THEN a$=a$+"Nacci"
IF a$="" THEN a$=STR$(q)
PRINT a$:r=p:p=q:NEXT
```

No declarations, used the `:` wherever possible because it's 1 byte cheaper than `CRLF`. Prefixed a 0 to the loop counter: Basic will overflow on the 47th Fibonacci character, so compensated for the extra byte that should be there.

EDIT: Neil saved me 3 bytes: 141 bytes.

Comment: You can remove the first `a$+` since it's known to be the empty string at this point.

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 127 bytes

```
(def f(lazy-cat[1 1](map +' f(rest f))))(doseq[x(take 100 f)](println(str(if(even? x)'Fibo)({0'Nacci}(mod x 3)(if(odd? x)x)))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(def fib (lazy-cat [1 1] (map +' fib (rest fib))))

(doseq [x (take 100 fib)]
  (println (str (if (even? x) 'Fibo)
                ({0 'Nacci}
                 (mod x 3)
                 (if (odd? x) x)))))
```

Some tricks used:

- That pretty little `def` that gives the Fibonacci sequence itself is [stolen shamelessly from Konrad Garus](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2010/07/26/corecursion-in-clojure/).
- `str` can take symbols as input. Crazy, right?
- Maps and default values are the shortest way to write `if` in some cases.

Comment: What is `lazy-cat`?

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος It lazily concatenates multiple sequences. In this case, it concatenates the first two elements of the Fibonacci sequence (`[1 1]`) with the result of summing each element in the Fibonacci sequence with the element following it.

Comment: Am I right in guessing that this is basically the Clojure version of `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)`?

Comment: @SohamChowdhury Yes, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 44 bytes

```
XX{_2$+}98*]{_B4bf%:!"Fibo Nacci"S/.*s\e|N}/
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=XX%7B_2%24%2B%7D98*%5D%7B_B4bf%25%3A!%22Fibo%20Nacci%22S%2F.*s%5Ce%7CN%7D%2F).

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>150</s> <s>143</s> <s>126</s> 118 bytes

```
main=putStr.unlines.take 100$0!1
x!y=d 3"Nacci"(d 2"Fibo"id)(show y):y!(x+y) where d z a f b|mod y z>0=f b|1>0=f""++a
```

ungolfed:

```
    main = 
      putStr . unlines . take 100 $ f 0 1
    f x y 
      = d 3 "Nacci" (d 2 "Fibo" id) (show y) : f y (x+y)
      where 
        d z a g b
          | mod y z > 0 = g b
          | otherwise   = g "" ++ a
```

Comment: Why `; ` instead of `;`?

Comment: Oups, missed that one byte @LeifWillerts :).

Comment: Well, seems like that "inspired" to improve much more :)

Comment: What does `d` do?

Answer (score 1):

### F#, <s>202 163</s> 149 bytes

```
Seq.unfold(fun(a,b)->printfn"%s"(a%6m|>function|0m->"FiboNacci"|2m|4m->"Fibo"|3m->"Nacci"|_->string a);Some(1,(b,a+b)))(1m,1m)|>Seq.take 100|>Seq.sum
```

This is an FSX (F# script) file

Comment: I am surprised that this works

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 75 bytes

```php
<?for(;4e20>$b=bcadd($a,$a=$b)?:1;)echo[Fibo][++$i%3].[Nacci][$i%4]?:$b,~õ;
```

Surpisingly competitive. Requres PHP v5.5 or higher. I assume default settings, as they are without an .ini (you may disable your local .ini with the `-n` option).

---

**Sample Usage**

```php
$ php -n fibo-nacci.php
```

Comment: WIth `-n` `bcadd` doesn't work even when `bcmath` is installed. Without `-n`  lots of stuff is output on stderr.

Comment: Works on my box(es).

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript (ES6), <s>117</s> 108 bytes

```
let s=[1,1],i;for(i=1;i<101;s[++i]=s[i-1]+s[i-2]);s.map(n=>console.log((n%2?"":"Fibo")+(n%3?"":"Nacci")||n))
```

[Try it online here.](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20s%3D%5B1%2C1%5D%2Ci%3Bfor(i%3D1%3Bi%3C101%3Bs%5B%2B%2Bi%5D%3Ds%5Bi-1%5D%2Bs%5Bi-2%5D)%3Bs.map(n%3D%3Econsole.log((n%252%3F%22%22%3A%22Fibo%22)%2B(n%253%3F%22%22%3A%22Nacci%22)%7C%7Cn))%0D%0A)

Sadly this breaks after the 77th number, because Javascript doesn't support numbers that high.  I think this is still cool enough to warrant an answer, though.

It generates the entire range of numbers, then iterates with `map` to print out the appropriate string.

Takes advantage of the fact that `console.log` prints on a new line.  Could also use `alert`, but that's more annoying.

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 78 bytes

```
01:n0\oo~o'F0ibo'\
aa:+1<}[3rn?/!?%3\!?%2:::::+}:}oa;?=*
ooooo'Nacci'/
00$0o\.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DQKs8gJj@/Ll/dzSAzKV89hisx0Urb0KY22rgoz15f0V7VOAZIGFmBgHatVW1@orW9rRZXPgio@yUmJ2eq63MZGKgY5Mfo/f8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>100</s> <s>94</s> 88 bytes

```python
a,b=0,1
exec("print(f\"{''if b%2else'Fibo'}{''if b%3else'Nacci'}\"or b);a,b=b,a+b;"*100)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P1EnydZAx5ArtSI1WUOpoCgzr0QjLUapWl09M00hSdUoNac4Vd0tMylfvRYmZgwW80tMTs5Ur41Ryi9SSNK0BpmTpJOonWStpGVoYKD5/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>82</s> 78 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to xigio

```javascript
for(n=a=b=1;n++n<102;b=a+(a=b))alert((a%2n?'':'Fibo')+(a%3n?'':'Nacci')||a+'')
```

Uses JavaScript's BigInt (not supported in IE) to get to get all the way up to 100.

Comment: 78 bytes: `for(n=a=b=1n;++n<102;b=a+(a=b))alert((a%2n?'':'Fibo')+(a%3n?'':'Nacci')||a+'')`

Comment: @xigoi Duh, I should've seen that... I had all the parts right there

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript ES6 112 bytes

```
var f=(a,b,c)=>{if(!(99<c)){var d=a%2?"":"Fibo",e=a%3?"":"Nacci";console.log(d||e?d+e:n);f(b,a+b,c+1)}};f(1,1,0)
```

As with other JS answers, fails after 73rd number because of js use of floats

Comment: Why `var`? You can save 8 bytes omitting it, making globals instead. There is no consensus saying that functions can't create globals. Also, you can omit `f=`, making an anonymous function, saving another -2 bytes. Final save: -10 bytes Final size: 102 bytes

Answer (score 0):

### Perl, 146 Bytes

```
use bigint;$a=$b=1;for$i(0..99){$l=($a%2==0?2:0)+($a%3==0?1:0);print$a if$l==0;print"Fibo"if$l&2;print"Nacci"if$l&1;print"\n";($a,$b)=($b,$a+$b);}
```

Uncompressed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use bigint;
$a=$b=1;
for$i(0..99) {
    $l=($a%2==0?2:0)+($a%3==0?1:0);
    print $a if $l == 0;
    print "Fibo" if $l & 2;
    print "Nacci" if $l & 1;
    print "\n";
    ($a,$b)=($b,$a+$b);
}
```

---

old version with 156 bytes...

```
use bigint;$a=$b=1;for$i(0..99){if($a%2==0){print"Fibo";print($a%3==0?"Nacci\n":"\n");}elsif($a%3==0){print"Nacci\n";}else{print"$a\n";}($a,$b)=($b,$a+$b);}
```

Uncompressed:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use bigint;
$a=$b=1;
for $i (0..99) {
    if($a%2 == 0) {
        print "Fibo";
        print ($a%3 == 0 ? "Nacci\n" : "\n");
    } elsif($a%3 == 0) {
        print "Nacci\n";
    } else {
        print "$a\n";
    }
    ($a,$b)=($b,$a+$b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, <s>157</s> 155 bytes

Golfed:

```
function g(n){a=!n%2;b=!n%3;a&&b?return "FiboNacci":;b?return "Nacci";a?return "Fibo";return n==1||n==2?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2)}for(n=100;n++>0;)console.log(f(n))
```

Ungolfed:

```
function fibonacci(n){
  if(n==1||n==2) return 1;
  return(fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2));
}
function fibonacci2(n){
  a=!(n%2);
  b=!(n%3);
  if(a&&b) return "FiboNacci";
  if(a) return "Fibo";
  if(b) return "Nacci";
  return fibonacci(n);
}
for(n=100;n++>0;) console.log(fibonacci2(n));
```

Saved 3 bytes thanks to [Cows Quack's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63442/fibonacci-fizz-buzz-fibo-nacci/63678#comment154471_63678)

Comment: Thanks! By the way, why is there a minimum comment length?

Comment: There is a minimum comment length to prevent comments like "Good Job!" or "+1" and stuff like that.

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος Why is there also a minimum amount of reputation to be able to post comments then?

Comment: Change your for-loop to `for(n=100;n++>0;)console.log(f(n))` It saves 3 bytes

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος OK, thanks. Editing post.

Comment: I am unable to run this, I get a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (ES2015), 99 bytes

```
f=n=>n<3?1:f(n-1)+f(n-2);for(i=0;i<100;)console.log((f(++i)%2?'':'Fibo')+(f(i)%3?'':'Nacci')||f(i))
```

Ungolfed:

```
// fibonacci function
var fibonacci = (n) => n < 3 ? 1 : fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2) // (implicit return)

for (var i = 0; i<100;) {
  var output = fibonacci(++i) % 2 !== 0 ? '' : 'Fibo';
  output += fibonacci(i) % 3 !== 0 ? '' : 'Nacci';
  console.log(output || fibonacci(i));
}
```

Comment: Use `alert` instead of `console.log`; it shaves off some bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## C, 121 bytes

Had to go full `__int128_t` for this to work. `printf` doesn't know how to handle a 128bit integer, so the last four numeric values will be *printed* wrong. Still, it was fun to code, so here you go:

```
__int128_t a,b=1,c;i=100;main(){while(i--){c=b;b%=6;printf(b?b%2?b-3?"%lu\n":"Nacci\n":"Fibo\n":"FiboNacci\n",c);b=c+a;a=c;}}
```

compiled with `gcc-4.8 fibo.c` on x86_64.

Comment: `while` is *always* longer than or as long as `for`.

Answer (score 0):

## Prolog, 182 bytes

```
f(A,B,X):-X<100,C is A+B,Z is X+1,(Y is B mod 6,Y=0->writeln('FiboNacci');(Y is B mod 2,Y=0->writeln('Fibo');(Y is B mod 3,Y=0->writeln('Nacci');writeln(B)))),f(B,C,Z).
p:-f(0,1,0).
```

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/CyJcgbTF.pl)
To run the program, use the query:

```
p.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3, 137 bytes**

Fun question with lots of new things I learnt in doing it. Python3 isn't a golfing language, but I suppose this isn't too bad

```
f=lambda n:n if n<2 else f(n-2)+f(n-1)
for n in range(100):t=f(-~n);x="Fibo"*(t%2==0)+"Nacci"*(t%3==0);print(x if t%2==0 or t%3==0 else t)
```

Hardest part was just to get it to only print the number

First line calculates the nth fib number. Second line joins Fibo and Nacci if it fits the rules an then it prints that string if it should else print the nth fib number.

Comment: `2else` instead of `2 else` for -1 byte, `n+1` instead of `-~n` because `-~n` is unneeded, `t%2<1` instead of `t%2==0` for -1 byte, `t%3<1` instead of `t%3==0` for -1 byte, `t%2<1or t%3<1else` instead of `t%2==0 or t%3==0 else` for -4 bytes. Total save: -7 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 642 bytes

```
/A/
Fibo//B/
Nacci//*/ANacci
//^/AB
/1
1^5A
13BA
55
89*233
377^1597A
4181BA
17711
28657*75025
121393^514229A
1346269BA
5702887
9227465*24157817
39088169^165580141A
433494437BA
1836311903
2971215073*7778742049
12586269025^53316291173A
139583862445BA
591286729879
956722026041*2504730781961
4052739537881^17167680177565A
44945570212853BA
190392490709135
308061521170129*806515533049393
1304969544928657^5527939700884757A
14472334024676221BA
61305790721611591
99194853094755497*259695496911122585
420196140727489673^1779979416004714189A
4660046610375530309BA
19740274219868223167
31940434634990099905*83621143489848422977
135301852344706746049AB
```

Answer (score 0):

### Perl6, <s>59</s> 58

```
say "Fibo"x$_%%2~"Nacci"x$_%%3||$_ for (1,1,*+*...*)[^100]
```

Answer (score 0):

## F#, <s>153</s> 134 bytes

```
let rec L c n p=printfn"%s"(c%6m|>function|0m->"FiboNacci"|2m|4m->"Fibo"|3m->"Nacci"|_->string c);if n<100 then L(p+c)(n+1)c
L 1I 1 0I
```

Edit: Used `decimal` instead of `bigint` which allowed using pattern matching. Stole the internal logic from the [other F# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63688/56157). My older filtering logic is in the below snippets.

One liner, same logic, 155 bytes:

```
let rec L c n p=printfn"%s"(if c%6I=0I then"FiboNacci"elif c%2I=0I then"Fibo"elif c%3I=0I then"Nacci"else string c);if n<100 then L(p+c)(n+1)c in L 1I 1 0I
```

Different logic, 168 bytes:

```
Seq.unfold(fun(p,c)->Some((if c%6I=0I then"FiboNacci"elif c%2I=0I then"Fibo"elif c%3I=0I then"Nacci"else string c),(c,c+p)))(0I,1I)|>Seq.take 100|>Seq.iter(printfn"%s")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 129 bytes

```swift
let f={$0<3 ?1:f($0-UInt64(1))+f($0-2)},m="Fibo",n="Nacci"
for i in 1...30{print(i%12<1 ?m+n:i%3<1 ?m:i%4<1 ?n:"\(f(.init(i)))")}
```