# Abstract Syntax Tree Golfing: FizzBuzz, Python

Tags: python, fizzbuzz, atomic-code-golf

### Summary

Implement FizzBuzz in Python, with the fewest possible tokens.

### Challenge

Write a program that prints the decimal numbers from 1 to 100 inclusive. But for multiples of three print “Fizz” instead of the number and for the multiples of five print “Buzz”. For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print “FizzBuzz”. Programs must be written in some version of Python.

For more details, see [1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

### Scoring

Your score will be equal to the number of nodes in the abstract syntax tree of your code, as reported by [this program for Python 3](https://github.com/isaacg1/ast-golf/blob/master/simple_counter.py), or [this program for Python 2](https://github.com/isaacg1/ast-golf/blob/master/simple_counter2.py). To run the programs, provide the filename of your code as  command line argument to the program. For instance:

```
python simple_counter.py fizzbuzz.py
```

These programs are based off of Python's [ast module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html). If you have any difficulty, let me know.

To prevent trivial solutions, such as executing a long string with the actual program, or hardcoding the output, there are some additional restrictions:

- No token in your code may be longer than 15 characters. The above programs will check this requirement for you. Note that for ease of implementation, the above programs count comments as tokens.
- Code execution/evaluation is banned.

If you have questions as to whether something is allowed, ask me.

### Scoring Heuristics

The following rules are typically enough to calculate the score of your program:

- Block statements are 1 points: `if`, `for ... in ...`, `while`, `else`, etc.
- Standalone statements are 1 point: `print` in Python 2, `break`, `pass`, etc.
- Variables are 2 points
- Single-token literals are 1 point: `2131`, `"Hello, world!"`, `True`
- Functions are 3 points (2 for using a variable, 1 extra): `print` in Python 3, `range`, etc.
- Operators are 2 points: `+`, `*`, `%`, `and`, `not`, etc.
- `=` is 1 point
- Augmented assignment is 2 points: `+=`, `|=`, etc.
- Parentheses, indentation, etc. are 0 points.
- A line containing an expression, as opposed to an assignment or an expression, is + 1 point.
- Having code at all is 1 point.

### Challenge:

The lowest score wins. Good luck!

Comment: I like this style. You have to go for simple programs rather than just short ones.

Comment: Do we really need [tag:code-challenge] [tag:ast-golf] for this? Isn't this just a specific form of [tag:atomic-code-golf]?

Comment: @MartinEnder The reason I did it this way is because the tag text for atomic-code-golf says "Atomic code golf is scored by the number of tokens of your program," and that's not the same as this, though perhaps only a pretty small amount.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## 33

**Python 2**

```python
for i in range(1,101):print[i,'Fizz','Buzz','FizzBuzz'][int(`300102100120100`[i%15])]
```

Answer (score 4):

## 46

```
for x in range(100):print('Fizz'*(x%3>1)+'Buzz'*(x%5>3)or str(x+1))
```

Comment: Can't x+1 not be stringified in python 3?

Comment: @DestructibleWatermelon Python 3 doesn't have backticks for `repr` as far as I remember.

Comment: Print can take an integer as its argument, was my point

Answer (score 4):

## <s>39</s> 34

```python
for i in range(1,101):print [i,'Fizz','Buzz','FizzBuzz'][19142723>>2*(i%15)&3]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 35

```
for x in range(1,101): print(('' if x%3 else 'Fizz') + ('' if x%5 else 'Buzz') or x)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 36

```python
for i in range(1, 101):
    print (not i % 3) * "Fizz" + (not i % 5) * "Buzz" or i
```

I think this is the shortest of the approaches that don't use large numbers / strings.