# Creating a function over multiple lines

Tags: code-challenge, restricted-source, tips, source-layout, javascript

I'm attempting to create a function over multiple lines.

## Parameters of the challenge:

1. Function returns 'barbarian'
2. Only 2 characters per line
3. 40 lines maximum.
   I keep trying to use a fat arrow to declare my function, but fat arrows don't seem to work if you don't have them connected.

Source of Challenge: https://www.codewars.com/kata/multi-line-task-plus-plus-hello-world

My current work:

```
f=
(
)=>

'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n\
s\
'
```

This works, but the ')=>' is 3 characters long. I really just want to know how it is possible to even stretch out the creation of a function. I can't find any info on it anywhere as it's obviously not very practical.

Comment: [Related?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/156129/take-a-stand-against-long-quine-lines)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Unfortunately, this challenge does not have an objective winning criterion, and I am voting to close this challenge until rectified. In the future, please use [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to receive feedback on your question before it is posted.

Comment: Also [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) would be a better place for this, if worded differently

Comment: @tfbninja Thanks for the heads up. I think I just will have to restructure the question. StackOverflow sent me here in the first place.

Comment: I think this is fine as a question asking for tips to solve a particular code challenge and have voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree with Laikoni that this is definitely asking for advice on dealing with a code layout constraint (i.e., restricted source) rather than asking a programming question like at SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a 38 line solution:

```
f=
[]
[
'\
m\
a\
p'
][
'\
c\
o\
n\
s\
t\
r\
u\
c\
t\
o\
r'
]`
r\
e\
t\
u\
r\
n\
'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n\
'`
```

It creates a function using the `Function` constructor, which it accesses from `[].map.constructor` using subscript notation (`[]['map']['constructor']`). This is the method JSFuck uses to create functions.

Comment: Are you not accessing `[]['map']['constructor']` instead of `[]['sum']['constructor']`?

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong, it returns 'barbarians' plural?

Comment: @cole The question's attempt -- contrary to the question's problem statement -- also seems to output the plural.

Comment: >_< sorry typos

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to shave it down to even fewer lines? Just curious at this point as this is the first I have heard of constructors.

Answer (score 16):

## 35 Lines

```javascript
f=
0[
c=
'\
c\
o\
n\
s\
t\
r\
u\
c\
t\
o\
r'
][
c]
`
r\
e\
t\
u\
r\
n\
'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n'
`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDkAwFET3c5HqgriAk/gSVSVE@qUt16/6C4ndvDczu7lNtGE7U@15djkvHdoetoMiWAITPCESEiEQLpFJfFAYynLA@DZO9CWr8ijviWAEv7BJ8ApjtuwjH645eK0WjR9WWucH)

Uses the fact that `0` is a number, the constructor of `0` is `Number`, and the constructor of `Number` is `Function`.

## 32 Lines

```javascript
0[
c=
'\
c\
o\
n\
s\
t\
r\
u\
c\
t\
o\
r'
][
c]
`
f=
_\
=>
'\
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n'
`(
)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtBDsIgFAX3cxFgofECeBF/Y5G2pqbhG0Cvj8qiibt5k3mP8A4l5vVZD0mnubXThegxQhRUSEIRqpCFV5e1@2wYvuXAyOK5Cv78O92E0Nsd1g7JMFpci5qKbvNx07tdHH/TOtc@)

This essentially runs

```javascript
Function(`
f=
_=>
'barbarian'`)()
```

which uses the [IIFE structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). Added bonus is that we can line-break some parts in the function body to reduce the line count.

## 24 Lines

```javascript
f=
''
[
'\
t\
r\
i\
m'
][
'\
b\
i\
n\
d'
]`
b\
a\
r\
b\
a\
r\
i\
a\
n`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYpNCoAgFAb330XURd2gk/QCzZ8wTEOl61u5CNrNDLOrSxWd/VmHmIxtzU1gDDMYoRIywRMOhqWXtWskmKfIV1V/PvAdomw6xZKCHUPauBP4KRei3Q)

Inline version:

```javascript
f=''['trim']['bind']`
barbarian`
```

Since all we want is to return a string, we can get away with a string method bound to a string. By using `trim`, we can also safely leave a beginning newline.