# Multiplicity Test

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Use any programming language to display numbers between 1 and 99 (including both) in such a way, so that:

- the numbers are separated by single space,
- if a number is divisible by 3, it should be in parentheses,
- if a number is divisible by 4, it should be in square brackets,
- if a number is divisible by both 3 and 4, it should be in both parentheses and square brackets (with square brackets closer to the number).

Your program should display exactly:

```
1 2 (3) [4] 5 (6) 7 [8] (9) 10 11 ([12]) 13 14 (15) [16] 17 (18) 19 [20] (21) 22 23 ([24]) 25 26 (27) [28] 29 (30) 31 [32] (33) 34 35 ([36]) 37 38 (39) [40] 41 (42) 43 [44] (45) 46 47 ([48]) 49 50 (51) [52] 53 (54) 55 [56] (57) 58 59 ([60]) 61 62 (63) [64] 65 (66) 67 [68] (69) 70 71 ([72]) 73 74 (75) [76] 77 (78) 79 [80] (81) 82 83 ([84]) 85 86 (87) [88] 89 (90) 91 [92] (93) 94 95 ([96]) 97 98 (99)
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz)

Comment: Can we output each entry on a new line, or must the output be all on one line?

Comment: Can the output end with a space. A few answers seem to assume so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
тGND4Öi…[ÿ]}N3Öi…(ÿ)]ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//YpO7n4vJ4WmZjxqWRR/eH1vrZwzhaBzerxl7eMPhvf//AwA)

Comment: -1 byte by changing `}?ð?` to `]ðý` (close both the if and loop, and join the entire stack by spaces)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: [-1 by using `Å€`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0vLwXJPDrY@a1jxqWBZ9eH9srTGMp3F4v2btoWWHNxze@/8/AA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>68</s> <s>65</s> 60 bytes

```python
i=0
exec"i+=1;print'('[i%3:]+`[i][i%4:]or i`+')'[i%3:],;"*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCu1IjVZKVPb1tC6oCgzr0RdQz06U9XYKlY7ITozFsg0sYrNL1LITNBW14TK6FgraVla/v8PAA)

Comment: I was right :) +1

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
"+"=c
r=""+""
cat(paste0(r+"(",r+""+"[",1:99,r+""+"]",r+")"))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X0lbyTaZq8hWCchQ4kpOLNEoSCwuSTXQKNJW0lDSAZJAiWglHUMrS0soLxYsrKmkqfn/PwA)

Comment: brilliant aliasing!

Comment: How does this even work? That's amazing! +1 to you my friend

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
³Ṗµ3,4ṚƬḍ×“([“])”j)K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Q5oc7px3aaqxj8nDnrGNrHu7oPTz9UcMcjWggEav5qGFulqb3//8A)

#### How it works

```
³Ṗµ3,4ṚƬḍ×“([“])”j)K  Main link. No arguments.

³                     Set the return value to 100.
 Ṗ                    Pop; yield [1, ..., 99].
  µ               )   Map the chain in between over [1, ..., 9]; for each integer k:
   3,4                    Set the return value to [3, 4].
      ṚƬ                  Reverse until a loop is reached. Yields [[3, 4], [4, 3]].
        ḍ                 Test k for divisibility by [[3, 4], [4, 3]], yielding a
                          matrix of Booleans.
         ×“([“])”         Repeat the characters of [['(', '['], [']', ')']] as many
                          times as the Booleans indicate.
                 j        Join the resulting pair of strings, separated by k.
                   K  Join the resulting array of strings, separated by spaces.
```

Answer (score 3):

### C, C++, <s>136</s> <s>133</s> <s>131</s> <s>129</s> <s>128</s> 124 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Zacharý and inspired by write() function in D language ( see Zacharý answer )

-2 bytes thanks to mriklojn

-12 bytes for the C version thanks to mriklojn

-4 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

```cpp
#include<cstdio>
void f(){for(int i=0;i++<99;)printf("(%s%d%s%s%s"+!!(i%3),i%4?"":"[",i,i%4?"":"]",i%3?"":")",i%99?" ":"");}
```

#### C Specific Optimization : 115 bytes

```c
#include<stdio.h>
i;f(){for(;i++<99;)printf("(%s%d%s%s%s"+!!(i%3),i%4?"":"[",i,i%4?"":"]",i%3?"":")",i%99?" ":"");}
```

Comment: Does MSVC let you do the `inf f()` thing?  Sorry 'bout deleting my comments, thought I had something shorter (I didn't)

Comment: @Zacharý No, i think the function is too simple and it generates a "f must return an int". BTW, your solution was 3 bytes shorter ( include compression paired with moving the incrementation of i )

Comment: I know, I thought that I had something better than what I suggested in the comments.

Comment: Dang, dotally forgot `printf` wasa thing. Couldn't you use the C stdio then?

Comment: Another thing you could use/exploit is the fact that, at least with gcc 5.3.1, you don't need the #include, and you can also remove the function return type.
Additionally, if you declare the `int i` outside the function (in global scope) then its value defaults to 0 and data type defaults to `int`. This would result in your loop starting at 0, and to fix this you could move the increment into the condition expression in your for loop, making it look like `i;f(){for(;++i<=99;)`

Comment: @mriklojn Good tricks ( with i++<99 ), but not declaring types makes it invalid in C++ ( at least not with MSVC )

Comment: Yeah, not declaring types always makes it invalid in C++.

Comment: -1 C++ optimization: `#include<cstdio>` (I think that works, not sure about `std` and the like)

Comment: @Logern No, i get a "undefined reference to printf" linker error

Comment: Suggest `")\0"+i%3` instead of `i%3?"":")"`. Also, I think you need to add `i=0` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @ceilingcat `i=0` is not necessary as long as the program is executed only once. the `i;` declares a global variable (“static storage duration” in C standard parlance) which is initialized to 0 by default. https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10

Answer (score 3):

## [D](https://dlang.org/), 110 bytes

```d
import std.stdio;void f(){for(int i;i<99;)write(++i%3?"":"(",i%4?"":"[",i,i%4?"":"]",i%3?"":")",i%99?" ":"");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S/n/PzO3IL@oRKG4JEUPiDPzrcvyM1MU0jQ0q9PyizQy80oUMq0zbSwtrTXLizJLUjW0tTNVje2VlKyUNJR0MlVNwMxoIBPOiQWJQ5RogpiWlvZKCkCOkqZ17X@w6bmJmXkamgrVXJxAe6y5av8DAA)

Ported from  @HatsuPointerKun's C++ answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
⪫ＥＥＥ⁹⁹Ｉ⊕ι⎇﹪⊕κ⁴ι⪫[]ι⎇﹪⊕κ³ι⪫()ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMrPzNPwzexAI4tLXUUnBOLSzQ885KLUnNT80pSUzQyNTU1dRRCUovyEosqNXzzU0pz8lEUZAOlTYA4U0cBbKJSdKwSkEeELmNkXRqaEF1AMSUFJU1N6////@uW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ⁹⁹                          Literal 99
   Ｅ                            Map over implicit range
        ι                       Current value
       ⊕                        Incrementd
      Ｉ                         Cast to string
  Ｅ                             Map over list of strings
            κ                   Current index
           ⊕                    Incremented
             ⁴                  Literal 4
          ﹪                     Modulo
              ι                 Current value
                []              Literal string `[]`
                  ι             Current value
               ⪫                Join i.e wrap value in `[]`
         ⎇                      Ternary
 Ｅ                              Map over list of strings
                      κ         Current index
                     ⊕          Incremented
                       ³        Literal 3
                    ﹪           Modulo
                        ι       Current value
                          ()    Literal string `()`
                            ι   Current value
                         ⪫      Join i.e wrap value in `()`
                   ⎇            Ternary
                                Literal space
⪫                               Join list
                                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

*1 byte less thanks to @Jonah*

```
(*stdout(3|.0=4 3 1 3 4&|,1=":)#3|.']) ([',":)@>i.100
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/X0OruCQlv7REw7hGz8DWRMFYwRCITdRqdAxtlaw0lYHC6rGaChrR6jpAroNdpp6hgcH//wA)

Comment: Thanks for doing this one.  Also, why do you have to do `stdout` here... I've never seen that before.  @FrownyFrog

Comment: @Jonah I can’t output it as a complete string, it gets cut off (. . .) stdout doesn’t do that, and it doesn’t print a newline either, so I can also print each number separately. For some reason though it makes trailing spaces appear (there are 4, and only 1 is intentionally there)

Comment: This approach is really clever, both the rotation and the choice to use `#`.  I had introduced an auxiliary verb to surround with `()` and `[]`: `g=. {.@[ , ":@] , {:@[`.  ugh the verboseness!

Comment: one more question: any reason you used `LF` instead of `_`.  the latter seems to work too.

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/create_explanation.py), <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>34</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
♀({îû)(î+╫îa_'(\')ßyΓî34α÷ä§
```

NOTE: It has a trailing space

Only my second MathGolf answer..
-5 bytes thanks to *@JoKing*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzAaN6sPr1DUOr3s0baK65uH5lYfXJcara8SA2ecmH15nbOJ0eP7h7YeXHFpeqFD4/z8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
♀(             # Push 99 (100 decreased by 1)
  {            # Start a loop, which implicitly loops down to (and excluding) 0
   û)(         #  Push string ")("
      î+       #  Append the 1-indexed index
        ╫      #  Rotate the string once towards the right
   îa          #  Push the 1-indexed index of the loop, wrap in a list
   _           #  Duplicate it
    '(        '#  Push string "("
      \        #  Swap the top two items of the stack
       ')     '#  Push string ")"
         ßy    #  Wrap all three into a list, and join them
   Γ           #  Wrap all four into a list
               #  (We now have a list [N, "(N)", "[N]", "([N])"], where N is the index)
   î           #  Push the 1-indexed index of the loop
    34         #  Push 3 and 4 to the stack
      α        #  Wrap all three into a list
       ÷       #  Check for each if the index is divisible by it
               #  (resulting in either [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], or [1,1]
        ä      #  Convert from binary to integer
               #  (resulting in either 0, 1, 2, or 3
         §     #  Push the string at that index from the array
               #  Push a space
               # (After the loop, output the entire stack joined together implicitly)
```

Comment: @JoKing Thanks! Didn't knew the `q` could be omitted and it's done implicitly in loops. Also, didn't knew there was a 2/3/4-string builtin. Too bad that rotate trick doesn't work with the wrapped array.

Comment: Well, it's more that I've traded the explicit output each iteration for implicit output at the end of the program instead

Comment: @JoKing Yeah, but I didn't knew it would output the entire stack joined together, instead of just the top. :)

Comment: My solution was approaching 40 bytes, though I misread and thought that curly brackets should be used instead of square brackets. Good job on the solution!

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 60 bytes

```powershell
"$(1..99|%{($_,"($_)","[$_]","([$_])")[!($_%3)+2*!($_%4)]})"
```

Explanation:

- the array with 4 elements: `$_, "($_)", "[$_]", "([$_])"`
- and the index: `[!($_%3)+2*!($_%4)]`
- repeat for each number
- convert the result to a string

Less golfed Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

$r = 1..99|%{
    ($_, "($_)", "[$_]", "([$_])") [!($_%3)+2*!($_%4)]
}
"$($r)"

}

$expected = '1 2 (3) [4] 5 (6) 7 [8] (9) 10 11 ([12]) 13 14 (15) [16] 17 (18) 19 [20] (21) 22 23 ([24]) 25 26 (27) [28] 29 (30) 31 [32] (33) 34 35 ([36]) 37 38 (39) [40] 41 (42) 43 [44] (45) 46 47 ([48]) 49 50 (51) [52] 53 (54) 55 [56] (57) 58 59 ([60]) 61 62 (63) [64] 65 (66) 67 [68] (69) 70 71 ([72]) 73 74 (75) [76] 77 (78) 79 [80] (81) 82 83 ([84]) 85 86 (87) [88] 89 (90) 91 [92] (93) 94 95 ([96]) 97 98 (99)'
$result = &$f
$result-eq$expected
$result
```

Output:

```powershell
True
1 2 (3) [4] 5 (6) 7 [8] (9) 10 11 ([12]) 13 14 (15) [16] 17 (18) 19 [20] (21) 22 23 ([24]) 25 26 (27) [28] 29 (30) 31 [32] (33) 34 35 ([36]) 37 38 (39) [40] 41 (42) 43 [44] (45) 46 47 ([48]) 49 50 (51) [52] 53 (54) 55 [56] (57) 58 59 ([60]) 61 62 (63) [64] 65 (66) 67 [68] (69) 70 71 ([72]) 73 74 (75) [76] 77 (78) 79 [80] (81) 82 83 ([84]) 85 86 (87) [88] 89 (90) 91 [92] (93) 94 95 ([96]) 97 98 (99)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
unwords[f"()"3$f"[]"4$show n|n<-[1..99],let f(x:r)m s|mod n m<1=x:s++r|1<3=s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoQgFADQfaf4iIuiJpBmU@gNZjdLcRGUNKTf8BsF45zdeW@baV@dK9/Kzx8EBceZ3im@EDiUE68QF9KW1Q0buGXasCenLVyAGeVDi74fR9O5NYGt7yk2Hij7sACCl0LdE7VtzEIOikz5lT8)

I wonder if `show[n]` can be used to shorten things up, so far to [no avail](https://tio.run/##jdDNisIwEADgu08xhoYmxBZLelEan2BvHocsKFqUbdKlqShsffZu/6CuruhpGGbmG2YOG/e1z7L6Z2I2RwsKvk/luiw@LHhQB8HJnvNi51BSwogQMSXYBHfIz2C7VDdpU@SkskmAURguFnqW7Usw1Ck0@Q4smDCc69XK6ckIpp2HvTRrA1qtp1M2/@yHYi5E@o@bKjawsmf5LYs@86utfimjz9u@e3yrBjqJHtSx8p4@9t9suXsBJ9JLCWoSe734cC27LAtuwA2cSSJ1WTohiipKpPrz0paj0ms5@sRjHUcNf@rV1/oX).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>105</s> <s>97</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```python
x=1
while x<100:print((('%s','(%s)')[x%3<1],'[%s]')[x%4<1],'([%s])')[x%12<1]%x,;x+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8LWkKs8IzMnVaHCxtDAwKqgKDOvRENDQ121WF1HXUO1WFNdM7pC1djGMFZHPVq1OBbMNQFzNUB8iLyhEVBEtULHukLb1vD/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>99</strike> 97 bytes

```
repeat n 99[a: b: c: d:""if n% 3 = 0[a:"("c:")"]if n% 4 = 0[b:"["d:"]"]prin rejoin[a b n d c" "]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYwxCsMwEAS/siwE7C4QNz7wJ9yKKyTdGeRCNiL/V0TczgzT3PruFrQ3vz1@UbGuIQqSIAtMyHKgvvDBhvcQnJiFM/XByx8nYeBolXq3UtH8vEoNEWn8DJmgau8/)

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>124</s> <s>117</s> 123 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```cs
x=>{for(int i=0;i++<99;)System.Console.Write((i%3<1?"(":"")+(i%4<1?"[":"")+i+(i%4<1?"]":"")+(i%3<1?")":"")+(i>98?"":" "));}
```

Test with :

```cs
Action<int> t = x=>{for(int i=0;i++<99;)System.Console.Write((i%3<1?"(":"")+(i%4<1?"[":"")+i+(i%4<1?"]":"")+(i%3<1?")":"")+(i>98?"":" "));}
t.Invoke(0);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Into the foray of C#, I see. Does C# allow integers as the left argument to a ternary operator, or does it have  to be a boolean?

Comment: I don't know much about C#, but could you use `x` instead of `i`,thus not having to worry about the `int `? (You'd still have to set it, of course).

Comment: @Zacharý No, it generates a CS0029 error "Can't convert implicitly int to boolean". And yes, i could use `i` and the fact that i can initialize it at 0 when i `Invoke`. But wouldn't that mean that i would have to include the declaration of t ( `Action<int>` ) and the call ( `t.Invoke(0)` ) in the bytecount ?

Comment: I'm asking if something like  `x=>{for(x=0;x++<99;)Console.Write((x%3==0?"(":"")+(x%4==0?"[":"")+x+(x%4==0?"]":"")+(x%3==0?")":"")+(x%99==0?"":" "));};` would work.

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, under one condition, that `t` is declared as `Action<int>`, and not `Action<Whatever_other_type_but_int>`. My answer works whatever generic specialization

Comment: All five `==0` can be `<1`.

Comment: Ah, the `<int>` ... okay, that makes more sense. And nice one @KevinCruijssen, totally forgot we weren't dealing with negative integers.

Comment: Does `(i%4<1?"[":"")+i+(i%4<1?"]":"")` => `(i%4<1?"["+i+"]":""+i)` work?

Comment: Don't you either have to include `using System;` or qualify it like `System.Console.Write`?

Comment: (That `System.`  adds to the byte count, by the way)

Comment: @Zacharý I forgot to complete the edit before saving x)

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, <s>161</s> 123 bytes

```
b=""for i=1,99 do;c,d=i%3==0,i%4==0;b=b..(c and"("or"")..(d and"["or"")..i..(d and"]"or"")..(c and")"or"").." "end;print(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctRCoAgEATQq8hCoCBR1E/IniT6SLdgITSkzr9JkV/DG2aOexXxCLCnrBh7O02KkguWkJsBsbPcjCWcR9@2Oqg1EmhIGcAU0@v5N9dqqZPvYn6Dgi2SOzPHS3sj8gA)

Ungolfed:

```
b = ""
for i = 1, 99 do
    c = 1 % 3 == 0
    d = 1 % 4 == 0
    a = ""
    if c then
        a = a .. "("
    end
    if d then
        a = a .. "["
    end
    a = a .. i
    if d then
        a = a .. "]"
    end
    if c then
        a = a .. ")"
    end
    b = b .. a .. " "
end
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 84 bytes

```c
main(i){while(99/i++)printf("%s%s%d%s%s ","("+i%3,"["+i%4,i-1,"]"+i%4,")"+i%3);}
```

There's a null byte at the beginning of each "bracket string".

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPI1OzujwjMydVw9JSP1NbW7OgKDOvJE1DSbUYCFNApIKSjhKDhpJ2pqoxkBENYpjoZOoaAjmxEI4SgyZYWtO69v9/AA)

Comment: And in "("+i%3 how do you know that address for i=2 point to a zero char value? The same for "["+i%4 for i in {2,3}?

Comment: It works with gcc, which is good enough, as PPCG defines languages by their implementations.

Comment: I think you can not say that code it is ok compiled in every implementation of gcc compiler, perhaps only the one run in your pc (but possible not too)

Comment: @RosLuP gcc _does_ work the same way on most computers though, at least on anything with the same architecture

Comment: @ASCII-only possible if is compiled optimized for space or for speed the result is different... I don't know if it is out the standard...

Comment: @RosLuP makes sense, but pretty sure they're normally compiled without flags unless otherwise specified

Comment: @RosLuP For code golfing purposes, [gcc with flags is a different language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/12012).

Comment: This program absolutely does not “work with GCC”. It happens to fly only tiny demons out of the author's nose when he tries it out on his machine so that he does not notice. GCC has never guaranteed that `"("+2` is in a valid page. The language description should be “GCC on my machine”.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, <strike>98</strike> <strike>82</strike> <strike>74</strike> <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

A whopping -31 bytes thanks to @Veskah
-5 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only

```
(1..99|%{(($a=($_,"[$_]")[!($_%4)]),"($a)")[!($_%3)]})-join' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1WkNDJdFWQyVeRylaJT5WSTNaEchRNdGM1dRRAkppwkSMNWNrNXWz8jPz/v8HAA)

I'm still not quite sure what I've done here.

Comment: Just some quick golfing for [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1OjNNQ1FDQyXRViVeU9VEU7MayFSKVkmMVaoFS6nEqxpDRYGqNJVqVRJrNXWz8jPz1BXU//8HAA). You don't have to cast $a as a string and `"$a"` will still substitute in the value. (Note: Single-quotes do not replace `$foo`, only double-quotes). Another trick is ifs only care about 0 or 1 so you can use boolean logic to save a byte

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1WiXRVkNJJV5JRylaJT5WSTNaUUMlXtVEM9YaKJwIFNZQSdSECRtrxtZq6mblZ@apK6j//w8A) if you use list indexing as well.

Comment: [also 67](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1WkNJJV5JRylaJT4WSGmoxGuCKBBXU0kzWhEooGqiqW2kBWYZa8bWaupm5WfmqSuo//8PAA)

Comment: [63?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1WiXRVkMlXkcpWiU@VkkzWhHIUTXRjLXWUEnUUQISmjBBY83YWk3drPzMPHUF9f//AQ)

Comment: [62?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8NQT8/Sska1WkNDJdFWQyVeRylaJT5WSTNaEchRNdGM1dRRAkppwkSMNWNrNXWz8jPz1BXU//8HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>67</s> 62 bytes

```powershell
"$(1..99|%{'('*!($x=$_%3)+'['*!($y=$_%4)+$_+']'*!$y+')'*!$x})"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0lFw1BPz9KyRrVaXUNdS1FDpcJWJV7VWFNbPRrMrQRxTTS1VeK11WOBIiqV2uqaILqiVlPp/38A)

Basically a [FizzBuzz](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58624/42963) using string multiplication times Boolean variables (implicitly cast to 1 or 0). Those strings are left on the pipeline and gathered within a script block inside quotes. Since the default `$OutputFieldSeparator` for an array is spaces, this implicitly gives us space-delimited array elements.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org), <s>72</s> 66 bytes

```
p [*1..99].map{|x|a=x
a="[#{x}]"if x%4<1
a="(#{a})"if x%3<1
a}*' '
```

Thanks to @jonathan-frech and @conor-obrien for additional trimming.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhWstQT8/SMlYvN7GguqaiJtG2givRVilaubqiNlYpM02hQtXExhAkpKFcnVirCREyBgnV6mXlZ@apK6j//w8A).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Here's another 4 bytes off of @JonathanFrench 's suggestion, for [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0AhWstQT8/SMlYvN7GguqaiJtG2givRVilaubqiNlYpM02hQtXExhAkpKFcnVirCREyBgnVaqkrqP//DwA), since `a.join b` for an array `a` and string `b` is equivalent to `a*b`

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

```javascript
f=(n=99)=>n&&f(n-1)+(s=n%4?n:`[${n}]`,n%3?s:`(${s})`)+' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHbCkBAFAXQX/Hgck4uJV5MDR8iNcKItEeOvMi3j7X28RllurbzzuHmxXurCbppWLeIY0vIS05JNKK6gzJ9@OIbTIao6kQZCl/52HCaBImfHMQdS3G4lSwx@x8)

Changed to community cuz the optimize rely too much on it

Comment: You could shorten significantly by doing ``${n%4?n:`[${n}]`}``

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcnRCkAwFADQX/FA995EiRfT7EOkaNYi3cnkRb59pDyezjKeo9f7vB0Zu8mEYCWyrGuSLSuLnBWUIielAhCA8KFSLIYuvvjuh3@jtykCEgCh0Y69W02@OosWicID) (with ETH's suggestion)

Comment: [59 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHbCkBAFAXQX/Hgck4uJV5MDR8iNcKItEeOvMi3j7X28RllurbzzuHmxXurCbppWLeIY0vIS06JRCOqOyjThy@@wWSIKu5EGQpf@dhwmgSJnxzEHUtxuJUsMfsf)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHbCkBAFAXQX/Hgck4uJV5MDR8iNcKItEeOvMi3j7X28RllurbzzuHmxXurCbppWLeIY0vIS05JNKK6gzJ9@OIbTIao6kQZCl/52HCaBImfHMQdS3G4lSwx@x8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## perl -E, 60 bytes

```
$,=$";say map$_%12?$_%3?$_%4?$_:"[$_]":"($_)":"([$_])",1..99
```

Some bytes can be saved if we can use newlines between the numbers: in that
case, we can remove the `$,=$";`, change the `map` into a `for` loop, while moving the `say` into the loop.

Comment: Are you *the* Abigail? Inventor of `/^1$|^(11+?)\1+$/`?

Comment: Wow. What an honor to have you here!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>51</s> 48 bytes

```perl6
put {$_%3??$^a!!"($a)"}(++$_%4??$_!!"[$_]")xx 99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtEShWiVe1djeXiUuUVFRSUMlUVOpVkNbGyhoAhSMB4pFq8THKmlWVChYWv7/DwA)

Comment: I was going to abuse the difference between lists and array representations, like [this](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVKhWiVe1djeXiUuUVFRQyVRR7NWQ1sbKGYCFItXVIxWiY/VrKhQsLT8/x8A), but I'm not sure how to get rid of the enclosing brackets around the whole list...

Comment: @JoKing I thought about that, too, but I only came up with this [51-byter](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@gtEShWiVe1djeXiUuUVFRQyVRR7NWQ1sbKGYCFItXVIxWiY/V1EvPLC5RqKhQsLT8/x8A "Perl 6 – Try It Online").

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 145 bytes

```
@set s=
@for /l %%i in (1,1,99)do @set/an=%%i,b=n%%4,p=n%%3&call:c
@echo%s%
:c
@if %b%==0 set n=[%n%]
@if %p%==0 set n=(%n%)
@set s=%s% %n%
```

The code falls through into the subroutine but the string has already been printed by this point so the code executes harmlessly.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 103

`for(;$i<1e2;$i++)$a.=$i%12==0?"([$i]) ":($i%3==0?"($i) ":($i%4==0?"[$i] ":"$i "));echo substr($a,5,-1);`

https://www.ideone.com/SBAuWp

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 100 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Text
```

```
join" "[if(n/3*3<n)m("("+m+")")\\n<-[1..99],m<-[if(n/4*4<n)(""<+n)("["<+n<+"]")]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3vqJ5Lq0FjIGFpGw6mDiY4AYdGqCmpn01WI3@vBV0OucmJ7e3o8Lo/PCwI3HKYDTu5qdAmjDs8Zmex1eITVBTSFZEk5pcvUEg0BpNcVOsC4HMUaDAHQcGrOtQZO02z6tKpm7WX1euy7mjAIIvaBcKDhKYlEk9/8ZPr6263GN2OMbdG5Uz/X@crAraT@4L)

Answer (score 1):

## [sfk](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html), 225 bytes

```
for n from 1 to 99 +calc -var #(n)/3+1/3 -dig=0 +calc -var #text*3-#(n) +setvar t +calc -var #(n)/4 -dig=0 +calc -var #text*4-#(n) +xed -var _0_#(t)\[#(n)\]_ _*_#(t)#(n)_ +xed _0*_([part2])_ _?*_[part2]_ +xed "_\n_ _" +endfor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9BDoIwEEWvMoFNaUMowoYF8SCUTAi0xqitKRPD7WsrbIxx@d@8t5jV3EIwzoMF490DaiAHXQdinu4zlK/JQ85sUTWirhool@ull19H0hvxpkwSiFVTgvSTt3/T9kg3vewYJeaMCjUkrkYE5B@QJu4eSo5seE6eTmNkeOZ4rEPIUNnIMxDaLvG7EN4)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Dana*

`i->{for(;i++<99;)out.printf((i>1?" ":"")+(i%12<1?"([%d])":i%3<1?"(%d)":i%4<1?"[%d]":i),i);}`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY/NqsIwEIX3eYohUEjotaj3bmr8wQdw5VJcxP4xvW1TkihI6bPXSXAWA9@cmZyTVr/0yozV0Jb/C/ajsR6c1x4LaEnKOj002fXtfNVn5ukVY0WnnYOLxoFNDAAHX9laFxWcYQIaUL0MlkDbgkRAqcJ4ZtS@L58B4bDg6jjVxgqFabrPcyXpIhst3dRC4HFz4sB3nMtUYLLZ7onFLSnvku8w@Y2YlBH@AgSJQP6Q37yo4DY@Hx25fU1jqJ5ii6snk@Z2B20bJ2lxirExfFCspYpp5@UD)

Alternative solution, 82 bytes (with trailing space in the output - not sure if that's allowed):

`i->{for(;i++<99;)out.printf((i%12<1?"([%d])":i%3<1?"(%d)":i%4<1?"[%d]":i)+" ",i);}`

Explanation:

`for(;i++<99;)` - a for loop that goes from the value of `i` (reused as input, taken to be 0 in this case) to 99

`out.printf(<part1>+<part2>,i);` - formats the string before immediately printing it to stdout with the value of `i`

where `<part1>` is `(i>1?" ":"")` - prints the space *before* printing the number *unless* that number is 1, in which case it omits the space

and `<part2>` is `(i%12<1?"([%d])":i%3<1?"(%d)":i%4<1?"[%d]":i)` - if `i` is divisible by both 3 and 4, `i` has both square and round brackets around it; else if `i` is divisible by 3, `i` has round brackets; else if `i` is divisible by 4, `i` has square brackets; else, `i` has no brackets.

Comment: Save a byte by moving the space to the beginning of each loop iteration `(i>1:" ":"")`

Comment: That would only work if I printed the result in reverse (see [this](https://tio.run/##LY9NasMwEIX3OsUgMEg0NnHaVZS6@ABdZRmyUP3HOLZlJMVQjM/ujERmMfDNm9F76vWiUzM3U18/dhxnYz04rz1W0JOUDXrqsuu/882YmadXjFWDdg5@NU5sZQA4@ca2umqghBVoQLUYrIG2BYmAUoXxxqi9Xy4B4XvHtFhbY4XCNC1yJekgmy2dtEJgkp8u@Q8Xt6S@S37G5DNiUkf4ChAkAvkhsCAEfuZcHshu21Uwm59/A5m9PWOmkVKLqyeT7nYHbTsnaXGNqTH8T@THo1Qx7ra/AA)) but would actually save 2 bytes instead of 1.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the same as the expected output as per the question, but thank you for the suggestion nevertheless!

Comment: The "try it online" links seem to be broken. I was thinking `i->{for(;i++<99;)out.printf((i>1?" ":"")+(i%12<1?"([%d])":i%3<1?"(%d)":i%4<1?"[%d]":i),i);}` ?

Comment: Ohhhh you're right that does work! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, 61 bytes

*-14 bytes, thanks to Dennis*

```
seq 99|awk '{ORS=" ";x=$1%4?$1:"["$1"]";print$1%3?x:"("x")"}'
```

## explanation

Pretty straightforward:

- `seq` produces 1..99
- we pipe that into `awk` with the output record separator (`ORS`) set to space so the output is a single line.
- the main awk body just adds "[]" when the number is divisible by 4, and then adds, on top of that, "()" when divisible by 3.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UMHSsiaxPFtBvdo/KNhWSUHJusJWxVDVxF7F0EopWknFUClWybqgKDOvBChqbF9hpaShVKGkqVSr/v8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 65 bytes

```php
while($i++<99)echo$i%4?$i%3?$i:"($i)":($i%3?"[$i]":"([$i])")," ";
```

or

```php
while($i++<99)echo"("[$i%3],"["[$i%4],$i,"]"[$i%4],")"[$i%3]," ";
```

(requires PHP 5.5 or later)

Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7ea8b8e434dfb5609faba67eefc6b9f680441ae2).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 78 bytes

```python
i=0
exec"i+=1;u=i%3/-2*(i%4/-3-1);print'([%0d])'[u:7-u:1+(i%3<1<=i%4)]%i,;"*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCu1IjVZKVPb1tC61DZT1Vhf10hLI1PVRF/XWNdQ07qgKDOvRF0jWtUgJVZTPbrUyly31MpQG6jC2MbQBqjBRDNWNVPHWknL0vL/fwA)

I envisioned this cool approach slicing `'([%0d])'` but I can't get the expressions any shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 46 chars, 92 bytes

```
{{0=3∣w:1⌽')(',⍵⋄⍵}{0=4∣w:1⌽'][',⍵⋄⍵}⍕w←⍵}¨⍳99
```

litte test:

```
  {{0=3∣w:1⌽')(',⍵⋄⍵}{0=4∣w:1⌽'][',⍵⋄⍵}⍕w←⍵}¨⍳14
1 2 (3) [4] 5 (6) 7 [8] (9) 10 11 ([12]) 13 14
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
i=0
exec"i+=1;t,f=i%3<1,i%4<1;print'('*t+'['*f+`i`+']'*f+')'*t,;"*99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWgCu1IjVZKVPb1tC6RCfNNlPV2MZQJ1PVxMbQuqAoM69EXUNdq0RbPVpdK007ITNBWz0WxFLXBIrqWCtpWVr@/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 25 bytes

```
jdmj]W!%d4dc2*"()"!%d3S99
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jdmj%5DW%21%25d4dc2%2A%22%28%29%22%21%25d3S99&debug=0).

```
jdmj]W!%d4dc2*"()"!%d3S99   
  m                   S99   Map [1-99], as d, using:
                   %d3        d mod 3
                  !           Logical not, effectively maps 0 to 1, all else to 0
             *"()"            Repeat "()" the above number of times
           c2                 Chop into two equal parts - maps "()" to ["(",")"] , and "" to ["",""]
                                The above is result {1}
       %d4                    d mod 4
      !                       Logical not the above
    ]W    d                   If the above is truthy, [d], else d
                                The above is result {2}
   j                          Join {1} on string representation of {2}
jd                          Join the result of the map on spaces, implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

```python
print(*[(i if i%4else f"[{i}]")if i%3else(f"({i})"if i%4else f"([{i}])")for i in range(1,100)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQytaI1MhM00hU9UkNac4VSFNKbo6szZWSRMsZgwS00hT0gCKaSqhKNMAq9NU0kzLL1IAGpGnUJSYl56qYahjaGCgGav5/z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
for i in range(1,100):print("(%s)","%s")[i%3>0]%("[%s]"%i,i)[i%4>0],
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/Py2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DH0MBA06qgKDOvRENJQ7VYU0lHSbVYSTM6U9XYziBWVUMpWrU4Vkk1UycTJGYCFNP5/x8A)

Ends with a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>19</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä┐r►U^îⁿ_╤▌,│☻£╡▬
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84bf7210555e8cfc5fd1dd2cb3029cb516&i=&a=1)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 76 bytes

Surprisingly, this straight-forward solution was shorter than the "clever" ones I could come up with.

```c
f(i){for(i=0;i++<99;)printf(i%3?i%4?"%d ":"[%d] ":i%4?"(%d) ":"([%d]) ",i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI1OzOi2/SCPT1sA6U1vbxtLSWrOgKDOvBCijamyfqWpir6SaoqBkpRStmhILpMEiGqopmiAxDZAgkKWTqWld@x@oSyE3MTNPQ5OrmoszTUPTmqv2PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 51 bytes

```perl
say map{$o=$_%4?$_:"[$_]";($_%3?$o:"($o)").$"}1..99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVIhN7GgWiXfViVe1cReJd5KKVolPlbJWgPIN7ZXybdS0lDJ11TS1FNRqjXU07O0/P//X35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 104 bytes

```clj
(apply print(map #(do(def s(if(=(rem % 4)0)(str"["%"]")%))(if(=(rem % 3)0)(str"("s")")s))(range 1 100)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck7CsMwEAXAqywbBO91Mk6bkxgXIpaCjT9ipRQ5vezGkGnnvR7L12JrCDmvP8k27xVbyPLAdGCKSQrmhBcsbuLkSU@Uajqo01HpyP/u74YWpbJcbWH/ROmk855kayc)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 70 bytes

```
99,:){X4%0={'[Xs']++}{X}?}fX]{Xs'[/_,(=']/0=i3%0={'(Xs')++}{X}?}fX]S*
```

[Try it out online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=99%2C%3A)%7BX4%250%3D%7B%27%5BXs%27%5D%2B%2B%7D%7BX%7D%3F%7DfX%5D%7BXs%27%5B%2F_%2C(%3D%27%5D%2F0%3Di3%250%3D%7B%27(Xs%27)%2B%2B%7D%7BX%7D%3F%7DfX%5DS*) (Permalink)

---

#### Explanation

```
99                                                                    Push 99 to stack
  ,                                                                   Make a 0..98 array
   :)                                                                 Increment every value in array
     {                   }fX                                          For X in array at top of stack
                        ?                                             If...
      X4%0=                                                           Condition: X mod 4 = 0
           {        }                                                 Is true, then:
            '[                                                        Push "["
              Xs                                                      Push X as a string
                ']                                                    Push "]"
                  ++                                                  Concatenate to "[X]"
                     { }                                              Is false, then:
                      X                                               Push X
                            ]                                         Capture all in an array
                             {                                 }fX    For X in array at top of stack
                                                              ?       If...
                              Xs                                      X as a string
                                '[/                                   Split by "["
                                   _,(=                               Take last element after split
                                       ']/                            Split by "]"
                                          0=                          Take first element after split
                                            i                         Top element as an integer
                              Xs'[/_,(=']/0=i                         The number X minus any brackets
                                             3%0=                     Condition: X mod 3 = 0
                                                 {        }           Is true, then:
                                                  '(                  Push "("
                                                    Xs                Push the original X as a string
                                                      ')              Push ")"
                                                        ++            Concatenate to "(X)"
                                                           { }        If false, then:
                                                            X         Push X
                                                                  ]   Capture all in an array
                                                                   S* Separate by a space
```

This does not output a trailing space.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 71 bytes

```cs
int i;for(;i<99;)Write("{0:;;(}{1:;;[}{2}{1:;;]}{0:;;)} ",++i%3,i%4,i);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/M69EIdM6Lb9IwzrTxtLSWjO8KLMkVUOp2sDK2lqjttoQSEXXVhtBWLG1YHHNWgUlHW3tTFVjnUxVE51MTev//wE)

-9 bytes thanks to @ASCIIOnly!

Leveraging the semicolon ([The ";" section separator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator)) to create a custom format string.

Comment: [:( close](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IIzOvRCHT1sA608bS0lozvCizJFVDqdrAylqhttrQSsNavbbayCoaRBmDWLEglqGVJpBS0tHN1NYGEqrGIMJEJ1PT@v9/AA), also I think it'd be fine just adding a space after every term like most answers are doing

Comment: Good call on adding a space after every number. Sometimes I take things too literally :) I'll update later.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 30 bytes

```
Lo1@=X%4?X:"[{X}]"X%3?U:"({U})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3yff0ME2QtXEPsJKKbo6ojZWKULV2D7USkmjOrRW8/9/3WAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 59 bytes

```php
for(;$i<100;$s=++$i%4?$i:"[$i]")echo$i%3|!$s?$s:"($s)"," ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNKxVMm0MDQysVYpttbVVMlVN7FUyrZSiVTJjlTRTkzPygULGNYoqxfYqxVZKGirFmko6SgpK1v/t7f4DAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript, <del>114</del> 96 bytes

```
[...Array(99)].map(_=>['[4]','(3)'].reduce((a,r)=>n%r[1]<1?r.replace(r[1],a):a,++n),n=0).join` `
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEADAr3iR7NK4WPRSMRXfEYJd0iAtaRK2Kvj6WK8zM3949TKV1yHlMVSf05pjoJifUC0R3UX4C12HjhYu8DC9VfbslFZwQuVIwvj2AYC1oOnTXmzrru1NtiiRt/mDZrywbpqEOpkj0pynNOyGivUH)

Thanks to [Conor O'Brien](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/conor-obrien) for helping me improve it :-)

Comment: If you haven't heard it yet, welcome to PPCG! You can squeeze out a few more bytes: `n%r[1]==0` can become `n%r[1]<1` (-1 bytes); `.join(' ')` to ``.join` ` `` (-2 bytes); you can use `[...Array(99)].map(_=>...,n=0)` to make the iteration section a bit more compact. You can overall golf around 20 bytes from this answer. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCsIwEADAr3iR7NK4WPRSMRXfEYJd0iAtaRK2Kvj6WK8zM3949TKV1yHlMVSf05pjoJifUC0R3UX4C12HjhYu8DC9VfbslFZwQuVIwvj2AYC1oOnTXmzrru1NtiiRt/mDZrywbpqEOpkj0pynNOyGivUH).

Comment: Some good tips, thanks @ConorO'Brien! Will add the improvements

Comment: Damn, both `.join\` \`` and adding `,n=0` to the `map` parameters are tricks I've never seen. Love learning new things :-)

Comment: Anytime! Glad I could help! :D

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 56 bytes

```
Echo@@({~Join^^S@_'Mask[4'3|_,["["'"]","("'")"]]}=>1:99)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP3/3zU5I9/BQaO6zis/My8uLtghXt03sTg72kTduCZeJ1opWkldKVZJR0kDSGsqxcbW2toZWllaav7/DwA)

### Explanation

```
Echo@@({~Join^^S@_'Mask[4'3|_,["["'"]","("'")"]]}=>1:99)
       {                                        }=>1:99  over each number _, 1 to 99:
                        4'3|_                                check if 4 or 3 divide _
                   Mask[     ,["["'"]","("'")"]]             keep the respective brackets
             ^^S@_'                                          fold over this list (seed = S[_]):
        ~Join                                                joining elements by the iterator
Echo@@(                                                ) print strings separated by spaces
```

### Alternatives

**58 bytes:** `Echo@@({~Join^^S@_'Mask[[4,3]|_,["["'"]","("'")"]]}=>1:99)`

**59 bytes:** `Print@@({~Join^^S@_'Mask[[4,3]|_,["["'"]","("'")"]]}=>1:99)`

**76 bytes:** `Print@@(&/S@{Mask[1'3'4'12|_,Split@$"${_} (${_}) [${_}] ([${_}])"] }=>1:99)`

Answer (score 1):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 61 bytes

```
VAR j=0
-(i)~j="{i%4:{i}|[{i}]}"
{i%3:{j}|({j})} <>{i<99:->i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v8/zDFIIcvWgEtXI1OzLstWqTpT1cSqOrO2JhpIxNYqcQEFjK2qs2prNICEZq2CjV11po2lpZWuXWbt//8A)

#### Explanation

```
VAR j=0                       // Declare a variable called j.
-(i)~j="{i%4:{i}|[{i}]}"      // The i label keeps track of how many times it's been visited. Set j to that value, or that value surrounded by brackets, depending o nwhat it is.
{i%3:{j}|({j})} <>{i<99:->i}  // Print j or (j), depending on i. Use glue (<>) to not print a newline. Go back to the i label if it's been visited fewer than 99 times.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `HS`, 103 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 12.875 bytes

```
ɽƛ4ḊßøB;ƛ⌊₃ßøb
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJIUz0iLCIiLCLJvcabNOG4isOfw7hCO8ab4oyK4oKDw5/DuGIiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 173 bytes

```go
import(."strings";."fmt")
func f(){S,F:=[]string{},Sprintf
for i:=1;i<100;i++{s:=F("%d",i)
if i%4<1{s=F("[%s]",s)}
if i%3<1{s=F("(%s)",s)}
S=append(S,s)}
Print(Join(S," "))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY-_CsIwEIf3PEU4KCRYS4sO0j-rg5PQURxK25RDmoYmTqFP4lIEN518Gt_GttHp7r47uO93uzfd-FRFeSmamrYFysfViPXu88JWdb1hAWjTo2w0JAGI1gAn4ipLKhi3ub-Ps9PZHdjBz9XUGEFE11OMsyjBNArDBFcrq-Nsz8CrwEdOUFD0tmlk9QxPnj6Dr_ng-ObPmae543lWKFXLiuXLeJy_sEOHcgJAgfPBSb8XszkE49SSSZH8NuPo6hc)

Prints the output to STDOUT.