# FizzBuzz but time-based

Tags: code-golf, date

Make a program that outputs the number of seconds from the beginning of today (00:00:00 of the day you run it) to the second you ran it. However, if this number is divisible by three, print `Fizz` instead. If it is divisible by five, print `Buzz` instead. If it is divisible by three and five, print `FizzBuzz`.

Don't pad the number printed with extra zeroes (44 instead of 00044). You don't need to take leap seconds into account (saying for the universe in which people answer this years after I post it). Standard loopholes apply, shortest program wins.

Comment: `Beginning of today` as in 13th of June or Midnight of the day you run it?

Comment: Midnight of the day you run it.

Comment: I know you're not a new user, but I still strongly suggest using [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to help iron out your challenges. The couple of days' worth of feedback is always well worth it!

Comment: This is a just a composition of an existing challenge with 'get the seconds since midnight'. I don't see what that adds.

Comment: I more intended this as a way to add a time element to FizzBuzz. I guess this adds text replacement but I dunno.

Comment: This is just fizz buzz.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

A simple port of [Dennis's "1-2-fizz-4-buzz" solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70216/53748) which evaluates the formatted time as seconds first

```
7ŒTṣ”:Vḅ60µ3,5ḍTị“¡Ṭ4“Ụp»ȯ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9qZWxsef//N8WSVOG5o@KAnTpW4biFNjDCtTMsNeG4jVThu4vigJzCoeG5rDTigJzhu6RwwrvIr///)**

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 73 bytes

```python
import time
a=time.time()%86400//1
print(a%3<1)*"Fizz"+(a%5<1)*"Buzz"or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVK9EWROmBCA1NVQszEwMDfX1DroKizLwSjURVYxtDTS0lt8yqKiVtINcUzHUqBXLzixQS/0OVaf4HAA)

-37 bytes using time.time instead of datetime thanks to negative seven
-4 bytes thanks to ArBo (switched to Python 2)

Comment: [77 with time.time()](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVK9E2M69EA8TUAxEamqoWZiYGBppcBUUgCY1EVWMbQ00tJbfMqiolbSDXFMx1KgVy84sUEjX/QxQCGQA)

Comment: @negativeseven oh huh, good idea. thanks!

Comment: You can save two bytes on the `print` parentheses by switching to Python 2. Also, if outputting numbers with a trailing `.0` is allowed, you can change `int(...)` to `...//1` for two more bytes.

Comment: @ArBo Oh nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

*-3 bytes from Grimy*

```
žažbžc)60βÐ3Öi"Fizz"?}5Öi”ÒÖ”,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7Eo/uSju5L1jQzOLfp8ATjw9Myldwyq6qU7GtNgexHDXMPTzo8DUjp/P8PAA)

Comment: `žažbžc)60β` for -3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>117</s> <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 71 bytes

<sup>-23 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>
<sup>-4 bytes thanks to AdmBorkBork</sup>
<sup>-19 bytes thanks to mazzy again</sup>

```powershell
(([int]$x=date|% tim*|% t*ls*),('Fizz'*!($x%3)+'Buzz'*!($x%5))|sort)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DIzozryRWpcI2JbEktUZVoSQzVwtEaeUUa2nqaKi7ZVZVqWspaqhUqBpraqs7lcK5ppqaNcX5RSWa0Yax/2u5uAz19AwNalSr1VTSrBWKc1JTCxQMa/8DAA)

An even cheaper way to compute the day's seconds. TotalSeconds also returns as a float so that had to be truncated as well. Plugs that value into [this Fizzbuzz answer by AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58624/78849) so give him a thumbs-up as well.

Comment: [TimeOfDay](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday) ?

Comment: You can just do `date` instead of `Get-Date` for -4.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork D'oh, thanks

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9DIzozryRWpcI2JbEktUZVoSQzVwtEaeUUa2nqaKi7ZVZVqWspaqhUqBpraqs7lcK5ppqaNcX5RSWa0Yax/2u5uAz19AwNalSr1VTSrBWKc1JTCxQMa/8DAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")?

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 145 bytes

```
@set s=%time:~,8%
@set/as=((%s::=)*60+%,f=s%%3,b=s%%5,t=f+b
@for %%a in (Fizz.%f% Buzz.%b% FizzBuzz.%t%)do @if %%~xa==.0 set s=%%~na
@echo %s%
```

Explanation: `%time%` is (at least on my system) formatted `hh:mm:ss.ff` so we start by chopping off the fractions of seconds. Then the shortest way to do the base 60 conversion is to replace the `:`s with operators and evaluate, and the divisibility by 3, 5 and 15 is also calculated. This is then tested and the number of seconds replaced with the appropriate string if necessary before being printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 24 bytes

```
t♪/╔%_╕Σ╠δ╕┌╠δ`+Γ\35α÷ä§
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/k0cxV@o@mTlGNfzR16rnFj6YuOLcFyHo0pQfMTNA@NznG2PTcxsPbDy85tPz/fwA)

### Explanation

```
t                          unix timestamp as integer milliseconds
 ♪/                        divide by 1000
   ╔%                      modulo 86400
     _                     duplicate TOS
      ╕Σ╠δ                 Decompress "Σ╠" and capitalize to get "Fizz"
          ╕┌╠δ             Decompress "┌╠" and capitalize to get "Buzz"
              `            duplicate the top two items
               +           pop a, b : push(a+b)
                Γ          wrap last four elements in array
                 \         swap top elements (swaps 2nd copy of time to TOS)
                  35α      push [3, 5]
                     ÷     is divisible
                      ä    convert from binary
                       §   get from array
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 45 bytes

```
%3,5¬ȧ"“Fizz“Buzz”o"““”Fȯ⁸
7ŒTṣ”:V×⁽½c,60,1SÇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/VWMf00JoTy5UeNcxxy6yqAlJOpSBqbj5ICIzmup1Y/6hxB5f50UkhD3cuBgpYhR2e/qhx76G9yTpmBjqGwYfb//8HAA)

This is so bad

[34 bytes if I steal Dennis's FizzBuzz](https://tio.run/##AUQAu/9qZWxsef//Myw14biNVOG7i@KAnMKh4bmsNOKAnOG7pHDCu8ivCjfFklThuaPigJ06VsOX4oG9wr1jLDYwLDFTw4f//w)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash, 154

```
z=$(($(date +%s)-$(date -d "$(date +%F) 0" +%s)))
[[ 0 -eq "($z%3)" ]]&&a=1&&echo -n "fizz"
[[ 0 -eq "($z%5)" ]]&&echo "buzz"||[ $a -eq 1 ]&&echo||echo $z
```

could probably golf down last two lines...

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <del>125</del> 120 bytes

```javascript
x=Date().match(/\d\d/g).slice(3,6).reduce((a,j,i)=>a+=60**(2-i)*j)
console.log((x%3==0?'Fizz':'')+(x%5==0?'Buzz':'')||x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcjRCoMgFADQ9/3H8N4yi8V6GLjBGPuKXkSlKZYjbUj07y7G3g7Hio8IcjbvWE1e6ZwTf4ioAdkoonxB3ate1QOy4IzU0NIO2azVshsEtdQgv4qSd01RwKkyWFg8SD8F7zRzfgBIx5bz5kaeZl3JhRAs9zr/6r78a9sS5vwF)

---

First line parses a date string for `[hours, minutes, seconds]` and adds them together, second line is just FizzBuzz.

Comment: [107 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcfdCoIwFADgp5Gdo3OaYRfRDCJ6im4Oc9rGcuFPDPHdV9Hd91l606RG85rzwbc6djIG2UCQV5o1oHjSrB5Q3Nus6FFMzigNFa9RjLpdvgbilhuUDWXyUKYpVLnB1PISMdmfdmd2M@vKjoxlIal/vyz/b1uIyg@Td1o430MHiPED "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online") (also fixes the bug that made your answer wrong in your reduce function)

Comment: Very nice, thanks! We don't have to put `console.log` in the answer?

Comment: Input/output methods are lax to a degree. Specifying a lambda is fine, so rather than outputting to a specific IO stream we just output from our function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 74 bytes

```perl
$t+=$_*60**$g++for(gmtime)[0..2];say+(($t%3==0&&Fizz).($t%5==0&&Buzz))||$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1@lRNtWJV7LzEBLSyVdWzstv0gjPbckMzdVM9pAT88o1ro4sVJbQ0OlRNXY1tZATc0ts6pKUw/ENwXznUqBfM2aGpWS////5ReUZObnFf/X9TXVMzA0AAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 76 bytes

```bash
date +'%H 60*%M+60*%S+[p]sc[[]sc[Fizz]n]sa[[]sc[Buzz]n]sbd3%0=ad5%0=blcx'|dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PyWxJFVBW13VQ8HMQEvVVxtEBmtHF8QWJ0dHgwi3zKqq2LzY4kQI16kUwk1KMVY1sE1MMQWSSTnJFeo1Kcn//wMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 40 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
{∨/d←0=4/3 5|⍵:d/'FizzBuzz'⋄⍵}60⊥3↑3↓⎕TS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94H/1o44V@imP2iYY2JroGyuY1jzq3WqVoq/ulllV5VRaVaX@qLsFKFRrZvCoa6nxo7aJQDz5Ud/UkGCQ/v8KYFAAAA)

`⎕TS` **T**ime **S**tamp; e.g. `[2019,06,14,07,48,20,317]`

`3↓` drop three; e.g. `[07,48,20,317]`

`3↑` take three; e.g. `[07,48,20]`

`60⊥` evaluate as base-60 digits; e.g. `28100`

`{`…`}` apply the following anonymous lambda to that:

`⍵` the argument; e.g. `28100`

`3 5|` the division remainder when that is divided by 3 and 5; e.g. `[2,0]`

`0=` Boolean mask where that is equal to 0; e.g. `[0,1]`

`4/` replicate those numbers for 4 copies of each; e.g. `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]`

`d←` assign that to `d`

`∨/`…`:` if any of those are true (OR-reduction); e.g. `true`:

`d/'FizzBuzz'` use `d` to mask the characters of the string; e.g. `"Buzz"`

`⋄` else:

`⍵` the argument; e.g. `28100`

Answer (score 0):

## [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), 90 bytes

```
$a=(@HOUR*60+@MIN)*60+@SEC
ConsoleWrite($a&(Mod($a,3)=0?"Fizz":"")&(Mod($a,5)=0?"Buzz":""))
```

It looks really bad without whitespace.

(FYI: AutoIt is a Windows basic-like scripting language)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 36 bytes

```
Js%.dZ84600|+*!%J3"Fizz"*!%J5"Buzz"J
```

[Try it online!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=Js%25.dZ84600%7C%2B%2a%21%25J3%22Fizz%22%2a%21%25J5%22Buzz%22J&debug=0)

Loosely based on the Python 2 answer.