Substring of Fizzbuzz
Decide if a string is substring of Fizzbuzz without separation 12Fizz4BuzzFizz78FizzBuzz11Fizz1314FizzBuzz....
Notice that it doesn't necessary cover whole tokens, e.g. zz78Fi is a substring.
Input will contain only letters and numbers, aka. match RegEx /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.
True cases
zz78Fi
FizzBuzz
Fizz1314Fizz
BuzzFizz7
69Buzz
33333333  (Any pure number appear in a large number that equal e.g. 1 modulo 15)
0  (for those who generate a few elements, make sure it's enough!)

False cases
BuzzFizzBuzz
78FizB
FizzFizz
Fizz1415Fizz
Bizz
A
78Buzz
012Fizz4Buzz  (Don't cheat the 0 case by appending a 0 before!)


Sandbox

Charcoal, 198 bytes
≔Ｅ01124⪪…FizzBuzzBuzz×⁴Ｉι⁸υ≔⭆θ›ι9η¿⬤⌕Ａη10Ｉ§θ⊕ι¿№η01¿№η10¿‹⌕η10⌈⌕Ａη01«≔⌈Φ⮌Φ⪪η1κκζ≔⊕⌕η⪫11ζε≔✂θε⁺εＬζ¹ζＦ¬﹪Ｉζ³≔∕ζ²ζ№⭆ΦＥθ⁺κ⁻Ｉζε›ι⁰∨⭆⌈υ×…λ⁴¬﹪ι⁺³⊗μιθ»№§υＩ§θ⊖⌕η1Φθ›ι9⊙§υΣθ¬⌕ιΦθ›λ9¿№η10⊙⌈υ¬⌕⮌ι⮌Φθ›λ9⊙⌈υ№ιΦθ›λ9

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Deliberately not brute force.
≔Ｅ01124⪪…FizzBuzzBuzz×⁴Ｉι⁸υ

Each digit has a limited number of alphabetic strings that can appear between it and the next digit. For 0 and 5, this is no strings at all, since those should be Buzz in the first place. For 1, 2, 6 and 7 this can only be Fizz. For 3 and 8 this can only be FizzBuzz (e.g. between 23 and 26). For 4 and 9 this can be either FizzBuzz (e.g. between 14 and 16) or BuzzFizz (e.g. between 4 and 7). The list of acceptable strings for each digit is computed here.
≔⭆θ›ι9η

Identify which of the characters are letters and which are digits.
¿⬤⌕Ａη10Ｉ§θ⊕ι

Check that no digit that follows a letter is a 0.
¿№η01

If there is at least one letter following a digit:
¿№η10

If there is at least one digit following a letter:
¿‹⌕η10⌈⌕Ａη01«

If the digit is surrounded by letters:
≔⌈Φ⮌Φ⪪η1κκζ≔⊕⌕η⪫11ζε≔✂θε⁺εＬζ¹ζ

Find the longest number in the input (excluding any leading and trailing digits) and its position.
Ｆ¬﹪Ｉζ³≔∕ζ²ζ

If it's a multiple of 3 then take the first half.
№⭆ΦＥθ⁺κ⁻Ｉζε›ι⁰∨⭆⌈υ×…λ⁴¬﹪ι⁺³⊗μιθ

Generate FizzBuzz in the vicinity of that number and see whether that contains the input.
»№§υＩ§θ⊖⌕η1Φθ›ι9

Otherwise, we have leading and trailing digits with letters in between. Look at the last leading digit and check that the intervening letters match any of the permitted strings.
⊙§υΣθ¬⌕ιΦθ›λ9

Otherwise we have leading digits and trailing letters. Look at the last leading digit again and check that the following letters are a prefix of any of the permitted strings.
¿№η10

Otherwise if there are letters followed by digits:
⊙⌈υ¬⌕⮌ι⮌Φθ›λ9

Check that the letters are a suffix of FizzBuzz or BuzzFizz.
⊙⌈υ№ιΦθ›λ9

Otherwise if there are letters then they must be a substring of FizzBuzz or BuzzFizz.

Fail Fizz1 (appears in [12,1]3, get False). Don't understand but random try give failure

@l4m2 Bah, Charcoal isn't parsing the code the way I want it to any more (I removed some tokens which I thought weren't doing anything but turned out to be needed to help it parse correctly). I'll have to come up with a fix for that.

@l4m2 ...or better still, come up with a golf that doesn't suffer from that problem!

JCram, 18 bytes (SBCS).
-2 thanks to @emanresu A
⍄πx②≠A⌿⍆P⍠⊔③H≥Ⓐ⍁⍚⍨

Encodes the following ES6 program:
n=>{s='';for(i=0;i++<1000**n.length;s+=((i%3?'':'Fizz')+(i%5?'':'Buzz')||i));return s.includes(n)}

Uses a similar idea to Dominic van Essen's answer.

Fails on 3 (should be true) - you need a higher upper bound

Shame! A fix costs one byte ;(

You can set both i and s to '', but it doesn't save any bytes at least with these variable names. Could potentially save a byte with some finagling though

If the upper limit is now 100**length, then won't it fail for 0 (first occurs at position 101)?   I had that problem...

18 bytes (you'll need to fix the exponent to whatever's appropriate): n=>{s='';for(i=0;i++<100**n.length;s+=((i%3?'':'Fizz')+(i%5?'':'Buzz')||i));return s.includes(n)} (using ETHProduction's fizzbuzz which the corpus seems to prefer)

@emanresuA awesome, thanks!

I think you still need a higher upper bound: 0 fails for the JS code...

Fixed, amazingly at no cost in byte count.

Nibbles, 49 48 47 nibbles (23.5 bytes)
Edit: -1 nibble and bug-fix thanks to I4m2
<<% +.,^;@,$ or:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz"@

Attempt a version of this Online!
Outputs a non-empty list (truthy by if/else) if the input is a substring of FizzBuzz, or an empty list (falsy by if/else) if it is not.  Two nibbles longer to output nonzero or zero (also truthy & falsy).
Searches the first 1000^length elements of the FizzBuzz sequence for the input string.  The link above exchanges this for 10^4 elements in order to run more quickly for longer input strings.
The double string "Fizz""Buzz" alone uses up 9.5 bytes here, so languages with a "FizzBuzz" built-in have a definite advantage!
We start by generating the FizzBuzz sequence.  The shortest Nibbles program for this (probably), by Nibbles creator Darren Smith, is presented on the Nibbles home page:
$?,:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz" = 36 nibbles (18 bytes)
However, this uses several tricks - implicit map, implicit range, 2 implicit variables - that need to be explicitly specified as part of a longer program, which would add to the program's length.
So here we use a (1-nibble) longer version :
$or:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz"@ = 37 nibbles (18.5 bytes)
This doesn't use implicit variables, so can end-up 1-nibble shorter as part of a longer program, if this is carefully constructed.
The rest of the program works as follows:
<< % +.,^;@,$ or:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz"@   # full program
<< % +.,^;@,$ or:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz"@$ # with implicit variable shown
           ,$                                # length of input
        ^;@                                  # 1000 to the power of that
       ,                                     # range from 1..that
      .                                      # map over numbers i in range:
              or                             # first arg if non-empty, otherwise second:
                                             #   1st arg:
                :                            #   join
                 ^                           #   replicate 
                       "Fizz"                #     "Fizz"
                  -~                         #     1 minus
                    %$3                      #     i modulo 3 times
                             ^-~%$5"Buzz"    #   to the same for "Buzz"
                                             #   2nd arg:
                                         @   #     i
     +                                       # now, flatten it all into one string,
   %                                      $  # split it on the input,
<<                                           # and discard the last element.


[Fails 0](Nibbles, 43 bytes: `<<`% +.,^~+,$~ or:^-~%$3"Fizz"^-~%$5"Buzz"@`)

If I understand the language correctly, there's a 1000 builtin, which can fix with 1nibble shorter(1000^n vs 10^(n+1))

@l4m2 - Ah!  I didn't think about 0 - thanks for pointing it out.  And thanks as well for the 1-nibble golf!  Updated with credit.  I hope you take up Nibbles golfing now...!

Vyxal, 102 bitsv2, 12.75 bytes
L↵↵ƛ₍₃₅kF½*∑∴;ṅ$c

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
011000100011101111110100001110110100100110110110001000111101010000010001110110000011101111010010010111

Times out for everything. Quite possibly because it's generating \$10^{10^{\text{length}(input)}}\$ items of fizzbuzz. Someone has to try the brute force method, right?
Explained (old)
L↵↵↵ƛ₍₃₅kF½*∑∴;ṅ$c­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
L↵↵↵                # ‎⁡Push 10 ** 10 ** 10 ** len(input) 
    ƛ₍₃₅kF½*∑∴;     # ‎⁢Average vyxal fizzbuzz moment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58615/1-2-fizz-4-buzz/210307#210307
               ṅ    # ‎⁣Join into a single string 
                $c  # ‎⁤Is the input in that? 


Created with the help of Luminespire.

I would have guessed that 10^length(input) would be sufficient, in order to comfortably include the worst false case of all-digits-except-last (which is always false if digits end with 5 or 0, and can be made true by adding at most one digit at the start, I think)...

@DominicvanEssen that's what I was originally going to use, but in the interest of ensuring a valid answer, I went for a few more powers than needed. The sufficient amount may indeed be lower, but I'm fairly certain 3 powers is definitely sufficient

@DominicvanEssen 10^length(input) fails 3. 10^10^len should be enough, though

Does 10 * 10^len already suffice?

@xnor - no.  0 first occurs at position 101.

For a slightly more performant version you can replace the first ↵ with T at no cost to bitcount

AWK, 81 bytes
{for(;++i<500;)s=s (i%3?i%5?i:y="Buzz":i%5?x="Fizz":x y);$0=s~$1?"true":"false"}1

Try it online!
{for(;++i<500;)                 # craft the test string
s=s (i%3?i%5?i                  # number if not divisible
:y="Buzz":                      # divisible by 5
i%5?x="Fizz"                    # divisible by 3 (from above)
:x y);                          # concat string
$0=s~$1?"true":"false"}1        # compare input and set output

